# How to check for strings between certain strings in unix scripting?

Tags: shell, unix

String:

```
name@gmail.com
```

Checking for:

```
@
.com
```

My code

```
if [[ $word =~ "@" ]] 
then 
    if [[ $word =~ ".com" || $word =~ ".ca"  ]]
```

My problem

```
name@.com
```

The above example gets passed, which is not what I want. How do I check for characters (1 or more) between "@" and ".com"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a very very basic regex:

```
[[ $var =~ ^[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$ ]]
```

It looks for a string being exactly like this:

```
at least one a-z char
@
at least one a-z char
.
at least one a-z char
```

It can get as complicated as you want, see for example [Email check regular expression with bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138832/1983854).

#### See in action

```
$ var="a@b.com"

$ [[ $var =~ ^[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$ ]] && echo "kind of valid email"
kind of valid email

$ var="a@.com"
$ [[ $var =~ ^[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$ ]] && echo "kind of valid email"
$
```

Comment: Sorry, but do you think you can explain further? I don't understand what ^[a-z]@[a-z].[a-z] is doing. And what the && is doing, outside of the brackets

Comment: Use `\.` to match a literal `.`

Comment: @Dan sure, just updated my answer with a proper explanation. The `[[ condition ]] && echo "hello"` perform the `echo` in case the `[[ ]]` is true. So this way you can check if you are entering in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

why not go for other tools like perl:

```
> echo "x@gmail.com" | perl -lne 'print $1 if(/@(.*?)\.com/)'
gmail
```

Answer (score 1):

The glob pattern would be: `[[ $word == ?*@?*.@(com|ca) ]]`

`?` matches any single character and `*` matches zero or more characters

`@(p1|p2|p3|...)` is an [extended globbing pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) that matches one of the given patterns. This requires:
`shopt -s extglob`

testing:

```
$ for word in @.com @a.ca a@.com a@b.ca a@b.org; do
    echo -ne "$word\t"
    [[ $word == ?*@?*.@(com|ca) ]] && echo matches || echo does not match
done
@.com   does not match
@a.ca   does not match
a@.com  does not match
a@b.ca  matches
a@b.org does not match
```