# Linux input pattern matching

Tags: linux, bash, input, pattern-matching, error-checking

I am developing a bash shell script that will allow the users their email addresses. However, I would like to check if the email is valid, just the form, not the actual email. For example,

```
tommy@hotmail.com
```

is a valid email but

```
 tommy#hotmail.com
```

is not... is there a way that would allow me the verify the input and prompt them for another input if it's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I today defined a very basic regex for it in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22508003/1983854, also there I link a very good one.

Comment: Hi, can I follow up on a question? what if i have numbers? how should i implement numbers into the script?