# How can I change the commit author for a single commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

I want to change the author of one specific commit in the history. It's not the latest commit.

**Related:** [How do I change the author and committer name/email for multiple commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)

Comment: I just wanted to make it my currently configured `user`, so what I needed was `git commit --amend --reset-author`

Comment: Checkout the [`filter-repo` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65685729/1814970), as it does everything for you using a Git recommended tool.

Comment: I did `git commit config --global user.name "your name"` and `git commit config --global user.email "your email"`, and then I did  `git commit --amend --reset-author`

Answer (score 5011, accepted):

Interactive rebase off of a point earlier in the history than the commit you need to modify (`git rebase -i <earliercommit>`). In the list of commits being rebased, change the text from `pick` to `edit` next to the hash of the one you want to modify. Then when git prompts you to change the commit, use this:

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>" --no-edit
```

---

For example, if your commit history is `A-B-C-D-E-F` with `F` as `HEAD`, and you want to change the author of `C` and `D`, then you would...

1. Specify `git rebase -i B` ([here is an example of what you will see after executing the `git rebase -i B` command](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/#an-example-of-using-git-rebase))

   - if you need to edit `A`, use `git rebase -i --root`
2. Change the lines for both `C` and `D` from `pick` to `edit`
3. Exit the editor (for vim, this would be pressing Esc and then typing `:wq`).
4. Once the rebase started, it would first pause at `C`
5. You would `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"`
6. Then `git rebase --continue`
7. It would pause again at `D`
8. Then you would `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"` again
9. `git rebase --continue`
10. The rebase would complete.
11. Use `git push -f` to update your origin with the updated commits.

Comment: @Mathew Byrne Or specify a1b3c3d4^ to refer to the preceding commit.

Comment: @AlanKrueger: How command-line will look like then? `git commit --amend --author="..." a1b3c3d4^`? Does not work for me :(

Comment: @dma_k The `a1b3c3d4^` part would be for the rebase command - e.g. `git rebase -i a1b3c3d4^`.

Comment: OK, I got it. So commit `a1b3c3d4^` should be the one proceeding my commits. Suppose my commits where `abc01^` and `abc02^` (and that one is also the last one). What are my steps to change author for both of them? E.g. what should I specify for [interactive](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) `rebase`? `pick abc02` and `edit abc01`? And then `git commit --amend ...`? Please, edit your post for this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I change the line from pick to edit but how do I continue... I am in a text editor but I have no idea of how to proceed after changing lines...

Comment: @toto_tico Just save the file being edited and then quit the editor and the rebase will continue automatically.

Comment: thanks @Amber but don't know how to save in this editor... is Ctrl + something?

Comment: If you don't know what editor you're in, the answer is likely `vim`. To save and quit, type Esc : w q Enter. On the other hand, if it's Nano and you see things like "WriteOut: ^O" along the bottom, then you should use Ctrl+O, Enter, Ctrl+X instead.

Comment: what if you want to modify the very first commit? What is the previous commit hash then?

Comment: One caveat here: rebasing flattens merge history, which can lead to significantly modified history, an even difficult merge conflicts while rebasing. To make git not do this, add the `-p` option to `git rebase `.

Comment: Amber answer is correct, but if you are beginner, this website is helpful to let you know how it's work. Visit http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/

Comment: Add `--reuse-message=HEAD` flag to avoid editing every commit message

Comment: @Amber As there a way to prevent git from asking me about the contents of each commit? I only want to modify several commits' authors - I don't want to edit the _content_ of any commits. Also, +1 for an excellent answer thus far.

Comment: @CHK see the comment immediately before yours.

Comment: @Amber isn't that the opposite of what I want? https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html says `--reuse-messages` preserves authorship. I want to change _only_ the authorship.

Comment: @CHK I believe explicitly setting the author overrides that (but feel free to test this).

Comment: note that you can set the commit author to the current user with `git commit --amend --reset-author`

Comment: Use `--no-edit` option. `git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit` won't open an editor. Available since git 1.7.9.

Comment: would I need to do a force push in the end?

Comment: You are awesome!.. Saved my time. Thanks.
Those who are not aware of editor interface, press "Insert" to turn on edit mode on screen while git bash propose you list of commits. Then, do changes as suggested in step 2. After you are done, press "Esc" to quite edit mode and press ":wq" + "Enter" to save and continue to next step.

Comment: doesn't work for me. But this does https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

Comment: You have to force push to git after you are done with rebase using command `git push -f remote branch-name`, to apply the changes to remote.

Comment: Same question with @Breden. I want to change author of the first commit in history. How to do it? What's the preceding one?

Comment: @amber You said change the lines for both C and D to edit, but what should i put?

Comment: @oshingc you literally change the word at the beginning of the line to the word `edit`.

Comment: @Brenden to modify the very first commit in the project, use `git rebase -i --root`

Comment: Does this keep a history of that change ? I mean is possible to realize that author name change after the rebase is done ?

Comment: @rahpuser not unless you have a copy of the older version of the history. rebase is a command that specifically rewrites history.

Comment: After follow all this steps I had to run ```git push -f```

Comment: Great answer, a quick way to get the <earliercommit> right would be to do HEAD~1.

Comment: How exactly does one point local back to the newest commit?  I'm stuck at 5 commits ahead of master now...

Comment: Beware this also changes your commit dates, which is generally an undesirable effect.

Comment: Adding `-C @`, e.g. `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com> -C @` will save you some steps. This will automatically reuse the commit message and the editor will not open at all.

Comment: If the base commit are in the same branch rebase is not performed, you need to use "--force" param: "git rebase -i B --force" in order to force the rebase.

Comment: if you've actually changed your git config (with `git config --global  user.name "Developer Display Name"` and `git config --global user.email "Developer Email Address"`) then `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"` can be shortened to `git commit --amend --reset-author`

Comment: git rebase -i --root to ammend the first commit

Comment: then finally how to merge those change into main branch? it refuse to merge when I was trying to do so

Comment: I think the answer should be modified to include option `-p` for `rebase` and explain what it does. In addition, `git push -f` should be replaced with `git push --force-with-lease` to teach people to use the safe method by default.

Comment: This leaves the old commits in the history, including the information we want to edit.

Comment: Note that the `--reset-author` option also renews the author timestamp, whereas the `--author="Author Name <email@address.com>"` option does not.

Comment: `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Author Name" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="author@email.com" git commit --amend --author="authorname <author@email.com>" --no-edit` This gets committer name update too apart from author.

Comment: You don't actually need to change "pick" to "edit" then do the commit --amend on the commandline -- you can instead add "exec git commit --amend ..." to the interactive rebase script immediately after any "pick" of a commit you want to change.

Comment: fatal: You are in the middle of a rebase -- cannot amend.

Answer (score 772):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042512/3357935) to this question is a wonderfully clever use of interactive rebase, but it unfortunately exhibits conflicts if the commit we are trying to change the author of used to be on a branch which was subsequently merged in. More generally, it does not work when handling messy histories.

Since I am apprehensive about running scripts which depend on setting and unsetting environment variables to rewrite git history, I am writing a new answer based on [this post](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) which is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3404304/391161) but is more complete.

The following is tested and working, unlike the linked answer.
Assume for clarity of exposition that `03f482d6` is the commit whose author we are trying to replace, and `42627abe` is the commit with the new author.

1. Checkout the commit we are trying to modify:

   ```
    git checkout 03f482d6
   ```
2. Make the author change:

   ```
    git commit --amend --author "New Author Name <New Author Email>"
   ```

   Now we have a new commit with hash assumed to be `42627abe`.
3. Checkout the original branch.
4. Replace the old commit with the new one locally:

   ```
    git replace 03f482d6 42627abe
   ```
5. Rewrite all future commits based on the replacement:

   ```
    git filter-branch -- --all
   ```
6. Remove the replacement for cleanliness:

   ```
    git replace -d 03f482d6
   ```
7. Push the new history:

   ```
    git push --force-with-lease
   ```

   (Only use `--force` instead of `--force-with-lease` if the latter fails, and only after sanity checking with `git log` and/or `git diff`.)

Instead of steps 4–5 you can just rebase onto the new commit:

```
git rebase -i 42627abe
```

Comment: Please put a note in there to re-checkout your original branch after step 2.

Comment: @Benjamin, That did not appear to be necessary when I did this. Are you sure?

Comment: Well, I don't believe it's necessary for step 3, but I had to checkout my branch to reattach HEAD for step 4 to work when I tried. At least I think that's what happened to me...

Comment: @Benjamin, Actually that doesn't make sense because Step 4 touches _all_ refs regardless of where your `HEAD` currently is.

Comment: This looks much clear alternative to the horrific `git rebase -i`. Never heard of this `git replace` thing before. +1

Comment: I have a few commits that need fixing. Can I combine multiple `git replace` and then issue a single `git filter-branch` (since it takes quite some time to run)?

Comment: @rustyx, I see no reason why it would not work, but I have never tried it.

Comment: For clean the refs/original/... backup see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7654880/1342186)

Comment: This answer is just workaround for people with horrible git histories, which consist of rebase/merge/rebase/merge cycle done until the whole thing was no longer rebase-able (or readable for that matter). The `git rebase -i` is *the* right approach for everyone else. Nevertheless, this is a good workaround.

Comment: @RustyX yes you can

Comment: any idea how to preserve the date on the commit? Now it's newer then the commits on top of it

Comment: @TudorCarean, I think there's a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git) on that, and I would guess one of those solutions can be combined with this one.

Comment: @merlin2011 step 4. Rewrite all future commits based on the replacement.Appreciate if you could have go more about it?

Comment: @FallingFromBed, All future commit hashes are based on the commit hash of the ancestor commit, and the ancestor commit's hash is based on its author name. Thus, if we update on commit, we must update all commits that depend on it.

Comment: I recommend using `--force-with-lease` instead of `-f`. It's safer.

Comment: @merlin2011, thanks for a great post.  I have actually tried it myself and it works great, but with a small change: after `git replace -d` in `Step 5` a `git checkout master` command seems to be needed. Otherwise I'm still on an unnamed branch and `git push` doesn't work there.  What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @LukaszCzerwinski, I'm glad you enjoyed it! I think my push configuration may be different, so I did not have to checkout master before pushing.

Comment: Re: "all future commits" part. I was attempting to change author only 3 commits back from HEAD, but _filter-branch_ started to change over 16000 commits, back to the beginning of repo time apparently. Is that really correct?

Comment: @mattwilkie, are you sure those commits are actually changed? I think filter branch will examine every commit,  but I don't think it changes every commit.

Comment: @merlin2011 Oh, no I don't know if they were changed. I aborted the operation. I didn't/don't see why changing a commit in the last day would need to go back to the beginning of time and search forward from zero.

Comment: @mattwilkie, If the commit you're trying to modify is very recent, I'd say you should probably be using the accepted answer to this question. I wrote this answer when I had to handle a messy history and the commit I wanted to update was a month old. I'd go as far as to say that if you have a completely linear history from the present time back to the point you need to change, there's no need to use `filter-branch`.

Comment: WARNING: be aware that `git filter-branch -- --all` is changing commits in all branches that the original commit was in.  If you don't have enough credentials (or you just don't want to change other's branches history), it's good to be careful with this answer.

Comment: When i execute `git push --force-with-lease` show me `Everything up-to-date`

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Please note that if you don't have a remote, you must skip the `git push` step and directly checkout your branch.

Comment: After using this method (only with local non-pushed commits, of course), github reports "entirely different commit histories" when trying to start a new pull request. Is this expectable or did I mess up anything?

Comment: @DanielGarcíaRubio, That is expected. Github tends to freak out when you do a pull request with divergent histories; you will find this to be the case with any answer that rewrites history. Unfortunately I don't know of a good workaround for this, since it seems to be a Github-internal issue.

Comment: If you have to amend the author of multiple commits, this script will help: https://gist.github.com/philipjkim/f032887427227b6ec5fcde34ab406647 (all commands in the script are from this ansewer)

Comment: what happens to the tags ? :/

Comment: perfect implementation to amend git commit message/author, thanks @merlin2011

Comment: @merlin2011 Do we no longer need to delete the old commit if we just rebase? That is, shouldn't "Instead of 4-6 you can just rebase onto new commit:" read as "Instead of 4-5 you can just rebase onto new commit:"?

Comment: @ShortM, I think you're correct. Will edit.
To be clear, the `git replace -d` does not actually delete a commit. It deletes a replace ref.

Comment: As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70892888/5049813), I needed to do a `git fetch` before my `git push --force-with-lease` (when I did, I saw a "forced update" to the main branch which seemed to do nothing)

Comment: I had created a repo with old creds, when I realized, I was looking for a way to update the root commit, but nothing worked.  All of the `rebase -i` solutions wouldn't touch the root.  This was the only thing that worked.  Thx!!

Comment: Technically, `rebase -i --root` should work to touch the root commit.

Comment: This worked great to amend my authorship, but now my initial commit is showing as after my second commit!

Comment: @TomWagstaff This seems unexpected and I'm curious. 
Would you consider asking a new question with a minimum example of this effect and linking it?

Comment: Sure, but let's just check we understand one another :-) - what I mean is that the datetime stamp for the "initial commit" is at a later time - the time I did the amendment - than the second commit, which has kept its original datetime. But the "order" e.g. in the commit tree is still correct

Comment: Ah, I think that is indeed expected behavior. If you want to fix the timestamp, you could try using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41997774/391161

Comment: Maybe massively popular answers that use git-filter-branch(1) should be retired.

Comment: Wonderful. I managed to encapsulate the logic of this answer into [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78050544/10237506). Check it out and let me know any thoughts/suggestions.

Comment: @ProQ And yes, totally right - `git fetch` was needed before `--force-with-lease`, even in my case. Otherwise it would always fail. I updated my answer to include this, and also sign rewritten commits, since I use [commit verification](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification).

Answer (score 411):

If you just want to change the author of your **last commit**, you can do this:

- Reset author for the current repo:

  `git config --local user.name "Alex Smith"`

  `git config --local user.email alex@email.com`
- Now reset the author of your commit without edit required:

  `git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit`
- Force push your changes without overwriting anyone else's commits:

  `git push --force-with-lease`

Note that this will also change the author timestamp.

To do this for the **last N commmits**:

`git rebase --onto HEAD~N --exec "git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit" HEAD~N`

Comment: No, it's not. Look at the OP: `It's not last commit.` So how would they `amend` it?

Comment: This is great, it's a shame it's the last commit only, though. I needed it on the latest two, fortunately, so just did a `git reset HEAD~`, ran your suggested lines, then did the next commit manually again. Worked fine!

Comment: Thanks! The --reset-author did the trick for me, since without it the author changes but the "commiter" stays with the old author details.

Comment: To fix my last six commits: First set the correct author for current Git repo using `git config --local user.name FirstName LastName`  and `git config --local user.email first.last@example.com`. Then apply to the last six commits using `git rebase --onto HEAD~6 --exec "git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit" HEAD~6`. Finally push it to remote Git repo using `git push --force-with-lease`.

Comment: @oHo I wish this was an answer so I can upvote it. This was the only thing that solved the issue for me, huge pain in the ascot this has been.

Comment: Agree that @oHo example works, is simple, and lets you control how far back in commit history that you want to change.

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was looking for. I needed to change the author on the last commit, and this did it in the most simple of ways.

Comment: @oHo This should be the best answer, simple and easy!

Comment: Hi @agfe2 OK I have pushed my comment as an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857920/938111 Please give me some feedback if you think the answer may be improved. Have a nice day ;-)

Comment: Hi @ClarkUpdike I have just converted my comment as an answer as you have suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857920/938111 What do you suggest to improve it? Have a nice day ;-)

Comment: Hi @Chris I have just converted my comment as an answer as you have suggested last year. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857920/938111 Any other suggestion? Thanks, Have a nice day ;-)

Answer (score 367):

Github documentation contains [a script that replaces the committer info for all commits in a branch](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) (now irretrievable, this is the [last snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20200823163529/https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-author-info#changing-the-git-history-of-your-repository-using-a-script)).

Run the following script from terminal after changing the variable values

```
#!/bin/sh
 
git filter-branch --env-filter '
 
OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Push the corrected history to GitHub:

```
git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'
```

OR if you like to push selected references of the branches then use

```
git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/develop'
```

Comment: This changes it in all commits, not just one. Funny thing, I did this less than 30 minutes ago.

Comment: When I found this answer after reading previous ones I thought it's worth giving a try and voila it did the job. However in my case it changed committer name only in initial commit. By the way, before I tried ideas from the first answer. Maybe it affected the system somehow.

Comment: Note that if you avoid using `clone` / `push`, you'll end up with a backup namespace `refs/original/`. I couldn't find a way to remove this namespace intelligently, so I ended up deleting directory `.git/refs/original` ,which worked.

Comment: Why does this result in changes to the repo if e.g. OLD_EMAIL does not match anything? For some reason a few (but not all!) commit hashes change.

Comment: this works, but in my case, when i try to do push again.. starts uploading a big `mb`, as if trying to upload a full git history again

Comment: My use case for this answer is: I have two github accounts, one which I unintentionally used to make commits. This script helped fix all my commits by renaming the incorrect committer email/names. Of course, if I've been committing with the wrong user from, let's say, 50th commit to 500th commit, there will be 450 diverged commits. Anyway, after running the script, as @andrej pointed out, you'll need to `git push -f` to force push changes to the repo.

Comment: The link is broken now that Github revamped their helpdesk, and I can't seem to find the old article anywhere. This is the last surviving copy of this script, and it's the only one that works for me.

Comment: Be warned that doing `git push --force ...` will overwrite ANY changes that anybody else has done. In most cases you really want to use `--force-with-lease` instead of `--force` to avoid fatal mistakes. In addition, if the remote server is used by multiple developers, it must be understood that all developers will need to switch to new history once this is done. Otherwise you'll get total mess if people start merging between original and rewritten history.

Comment: The link is now broken. This is the last snapshot of it on the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20200823163529/https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-author-info#changing-the-git-history-of-your-repository-using-a-script

Note: the only difference from the answer is that GitHub suggests to use a clean bare repo for applying this trick and then delete it:

```git clone --bare <repo_url>```

Answer (score 137):

You can change author of last commit using the command below.

`git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"`

However, if you want to change more than one commits author name, it's a bit tricky. You need to start an interactive rebase then mark commits as edit then amend them one by one and finish.

1. Start rebasing with `git rebase -i`.
2. Change the `pick` keyword to `edit` for the commits you want to change the author name.
3. Then close the editor. For the beginners, hit `Escape` then type `:wq` and hit `Enter`.

Then you will see your terminal like nothing happened. Actually you are in the middle of an interactive rebase. Now it's time to amend your commit's author name using the command above. It will open the editor again. Quit and continue rebase with `git rebase --continue`. Repeat the same for the commit count you want to edit. You can make sure that interactive rebase finished when you get the `No rebase in progress?` message.

Comment: If you got multiple commits to change, instead of editing them individually, you can also let the `pick` action, and add after each line `exec git commit --no-edit --amend --author="MyNewAuthor <my@new-auth.or>"`

Comment: I am not related to the site in the link, but I have used this link https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email/, and then combined with this post (I used `rebase -i -p`), but at the end this is what I needed. Thanks

Comment: For beginners run `git config --global core.editor nano` before running `git commit` and then you can use Ctrl+O, Ctrl+X to exit the editor.

Answer (score 80):

#### To fix authoring on the last six commits

1. First set the correct author for current Git repo

   ```
   git config --local user.name "FirstName LastName"
   git config --local user.email first.last@example.com
   ```
2. Then apply the fix to the last six commits

   ```
   git rebase --onto HEAD~6 --exec "git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit" HEAD~6
   ```
3. Finally force push to the remote Git repo

   ```
   git push --force-with-lease
   ```

Comment: In my case I had to quote the name, like `"FirstName LastName"`, just a heads up

Comment: @DanielGalarza yep, multiple strings must be inside quotes

Comment: one more heads up, this will REWRITE the commit, which means it'll change the commit time as well. it happened as I wasn't aware initially when I ran the command. this is sweet and simple way if timestamp is not of concern. :)

Comment: Works really well! Needed to update my remote on Github, updated remotely instantly. Top-notch steps!

Comment: Had issues with higher ranked solutions. This one worked for me to just change author of last commit. Just used "HEAD" without addition of ~N on rebase. Thanks @peter-mortensen and oho

Answer (score 68):

The answers in the question to which you linked are good answers and cover your situation (the other question is more general since it involves rewriting multiple commits).

As an excuse to try out `git filter-branch`, I wrote a script to rewrite the Author Name and/or Author Email for a given commit:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

#
# Change the author name and/or email of a single commit.
#
# change-author [-f] commit-to-change [branch-to-rewrite [new-name [new-email]]]
#
#     If -f is supplied it is passed to "git filter-branch".
#
#     If <branch-to-rewrite> is not provided or is empty HEAD will be used.
#     Use "--all" or a space separated list (e.g. "master next") to rewrite
#     multiple branches.
#
#     If <new-name> (or <new-email>) is not provided or is empty, the normal
#     user.name (user.email) Git configuration value will be used.
#

force=''
if test "x$1" = "x-f"; then
    force='-f'
    shift
fi

die() {
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
    exit 128
}
targ="$(git rev-parse --verify "$1" 2>/dev/null)" || die "$1 is not a commit"
br="${2:-HEAD}"

TARG_COMMIT="$targ"
TARG_NAME="${3-}"
TARG_EMAIL="${4-}"
export TARG_COMMIT TARG_NAME TARG_EMAIL

filt='

    if test "$GIT_COMMIT" = "$TARG_COMMIT"; then
        if test -n "$TARG_EMAIL"; then
            GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$TARG_EMAIL"
            export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
        else
            unset GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
        fi
        if test -n "$TARG_NAME"; then
            GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$TARG_NAME"
            export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
        else
            unset GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
        fi
    fi

'

git filter-branch $force --env-filter "$filt" -- $br
```

Comment: +1 thanks.  assembla.com git repo doesn't appear to change all author references in the web view of the repo, but the results of 'git pull/clone' appear to all work ok.

Comment: Great solution, as it only change what's intended, and not other fields, like commit date.

Comment: Github documentation contains a [similar script](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info)

Comment: @olivieradam666 that works like a charm and it's easier to read

Comment: @olivieradam666 Thank you. You should really add that as an answer so it gets more attention.

Comment: Note you are not resetting `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`/`GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, which usually are the same as author mail/name.

Comment: ```for var in "$@"
do
 ./script.sh -f $var <branch-name> "name" email
done
```
Use this for multiple commits, by passing multiple commit ids as arguments to this script

Answer (score 57):

Find a way that can change user quickly and has no side effect to others commits.

#### Simple and clear way:

```sh
git config user.name "New User"
git config user.email "newuser@gmail.com"

git log
git rebase -i 1f1357
# change the word 'pick' to 'edit', save and exit

git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
git rebase --continue

git push --force-with-lease
```

#### detailed operations

- show commit logs and find out the commit id that ahead of your commit which you want to change:

```sh
git log
```

- git rebase start from the chosed commit id to the recent reversely:

```sh
git config user.name "New User"
git config user.email "newuser@gmail.com"
git rebase -i 1f1357

# change word pick to edit, save and exit
edit 809b8f7 change code order 
pick 9baaae5 add prometheus monitor kubernetes
edit 5d726c3 fix liquid escape issue   
edit 3a5f98f update tags
pick 816e21c add prometheus monitor kubernetes
```

- rebase will Stopped at next commit id, output:

```sh
Stopped at 809b8f7...  change code order 
You can amend the commit now, with
  git commit --amend 

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

  git rebase --continue
```

- comfirm and continue your rebase untill it successfully to `refs/heads/master.`

```sh
# each continue will show you an amend message
# use git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit to comfirm
# use git rebase --skip to skip
git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
git rebase --continue
git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
...
git rebase --continue
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

- git push to update

```sh
git push --force-with-lease
```

Comment: Does first solution works if commit I want to change is first commit and there are 3 commits after it ? @NOZUONOHIGH

Comment: The danger here is that you change `user.name` and `user.email` in config but then don't change them back. If you don't change them back all _future_ commits will be by the new user too! This is why it might be better to use the `--author` flag on `git commit` instead.

Comment: this one, the Simple version, worked like a charm

Answer (score 52):

Commit before:

[image]

To fix author for all commits you can apply command from @Amber's answer:

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
```

Or to reuse your name and email you can just write:

```
git commit --amend --author=Eugen
```

Commit after the command:

[image]

For example to change all starting from `4025621`:

[image]

You must run:

```
git rebase --onto 4025621 --exec "git commit --amend --author=Eugen" 4025621
```

*Note: To include an author containing spaces such as a name and email address, the author must be surrounded by escaped quotes.  For example:*

```
git rebase --onto 4025621 --exec "git commit --amend --author=\"Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>\"" 4025621
```

or add this alias into `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    reauthor = !bash -c 'git rebase --onto $1 --exec \"git commit --amend --author=$2\" $1' --
```

And then run:

```
git reauthor 4025621 Eugen
```

Comment: To verify that the command worked as expected, I reviewed the output of `git shortlog -e -s`.

Comment: This is the answer that best served my purposes, thank you. And since I just wanted to adjust *my* e-mail address, I could run with --exec="git commit --amend --reset-author", after updating my .git/config.

Comment: Eeh, not sure why I forgot! Done now.

Comment: Great answer and very easy to fix.  Love the alias!

Comment: that didn't help me. now I have **Continue Rebase Failed** error

Answer (score 44):

In furtherance to [Eugen Konkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4632019/eugen-konkov) answer, to start from the root commit, use `--root` flag. The `--no-edit` flag is helpful too, because with it you are not prompted into an editor for each commit.

```
git rebase --root --exec "git commit --amend --author='name <email>' --no-edit"
```

Comment: I was trying for root commit and here Is the solution. Thanks

Comment: This is the simple and direct solution, changing the --root did the job, instead of mentioning each commit ID manually or mentioning HEAD~N

Answer (score 19):

When doing `git rebase -i` there is this interesting bit in the doc:

> If you want to fold two or more commits into one, replace the command `"pick"` for the second and subsequent commits with `"squash"` or `"fixup"`. If the commits had different authors, the folded commit will be attributed to the author of the first commit. The suggested commit message for the folded commit is the concatenation of the commit messages of the first commit and of those with the `"squash"` command, but omits the commit messages of commits with the `"fixup"` command.

- If you have an history of `A-B-C-D-E-F`,
- and you want to change commits `B` and `D` (= 2 commits),

then you can do:

- `git config user.name "Correct new name"`
- `git config user.email "correct@new.email"`
- create empty commits (one for each commit):

  - you need a message for rebase purpose
  - `git commit --allow-empty -m "empty"`
- start the rebase operation

  - `git rebase -i B^`
  - `B^` selects the parent of `B`.
- you will want to put one empty commit **before** each commit to modify
- you will want to change `pick` to `squash` for those.

Example of what `git rebase -i B^` will give you:

```
pick sha-commit-B some message
pick sha-commit-C some message
pick sha-commit-D some message
pick sha-commit-E some message
pick sha-commit-F some message
# pick sha-commit-empty1 empty
# pick sha-commit-empty2 empty
```

change that to:

```
# change commit B's author
pick sha-commit-empty1 empty
squash sha-commit-B some message
# leave commit C alone
pick sha-commit-C some message
# change commit D's author
pick sha-commit-empty2 empty
squash sha-commit-D some message
# leave commit E-F alone
pick sha-commit-E some message
pick sha-commit-F some message
```

It will prompt you to edit the messages:

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# The first commit's message is:

empty

# This is the 2nd commit message:

...some useful commit message there...
```

and you can just remove the first few lines.

Answer (score 19):

There is one additional step to [Amber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042512/1064325) if you're using a centralized repository:

`git push -f` to force the update of the central repository.

Be careful that there are not a lot of people working on the same branch because it can ruin consistency.

Answer (score 13):

**SOLUTION**

1. Install [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) *(Git project [recommends `filter-repo` over `filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning))*

   ```bash
   $ PACKAGE_TOOL install git-filter-repo
   ```
2. Create a file `.mailmap` in the root of the git repository containing

   ```
   New Name <new@ema.il> <old@ema.il>
   ```
3. Run `git filter-repo --use-mailmap`

---

**MORE DETAILS**

- `git-filter-repo` lists this as [an example in their docs](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#changing-authorcommittertagger-information)
- Instead of replacing both the name and the email like in the example above, take a look at **additional examples** in [git mailmap documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/mailmap.txt)
- Instead of using a file named `.mailmap` by default, you can specify mailmap file by invoking `git filter-repo` with argument `--mailmap <filename>`.
- Many more examples on how to further filter branch/tag/whatever can be found in the `git-filter-repo` [project's README.md](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo).

Comment: `brew install git-filter-repo` works in a Mac.

Comment: Confirmed. `brew` install works for Mac users and running `git filter-repo --use-mailmap` does the magic!

Have to mention that this method allows multiple author changes. Just press Enter  and add many lines as you need:
`New Name1 <new1@ema.il> <old1@ema.il>
New Name2 <new2@ema.il> <old2@ema.il>`

Comment: git-filter-repo is the best Git maintenance tool I've ever found. I love it so much and I'm grateful to find yet another cool thing to add.

Comment: Incredibly simple and clean.

Comment: Best solution, as it's simple and maintains date!

Answer (score 11):

If the commit that you want to change is not the last commit, then follow the below steps. If your commit is in different branch then first switch to that branch.

**git checkout branch_name**

Find commit before the commit that you want to change and find its hash. Then issue rebase command.

**git rebase -i -p hash of commit**

Then an editor will open and enter 'edit' for the commits that you want to change. Leave others with default 'pick' option. Once changed enter 'esc' key and wq! to exit.

Then issue git commit command with amendment option.

**git commit --amend --author="Username email" --no-edit**

Then issue the following command.

**git rebase --continue**

Once commit author is updated in the local repository, push the changes to the remote repository.

Answer (score 9):

**Using Interactive Rebase**

```
git rebase -i -p <some HEAD before all of your bad commits>
```

Then mark all of your bad commits as "edit" in the rebase file, and when Git asks you to amend each commit, do

```
git commit --amend --author "New Author Name <email@address.com>"
```

Edit or just close the editor that opens, and then do

```
git rebase --continue
```

to continue the rebase.

You could skip opening the editor altogether here by appending `--no-edit` so that the command will be:

```
git commit --amend --author "New Author Name <email@address.com>" --no-edit && \
git rebase --continue
```

Single Commit

As some of the commenters have noted, if you just want to change the most recent commit, the *rebase* command is not necessary. Just do

```
git commit --amend --author "New Author Name <email@address.com>"
```

This will change the author to the name specified, but the committer will be set to your configured user in git config user.name and git config user.email. If you want to set the committer to something you specify, this will set both the author and the committer:

```
git -c user.name="New Author Name" -c user.email=email@address.com commit --amend --reset-author
```

Answer (score 8):

For the merge commit message, I found that I cannot amend it by using `rebase`, at least on gitlab. It shows the merge as a commit but I cannot rebase onto that #sha. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599494/how-to-edit-the-commit-message-of-a-git-merge) post is helpful.

```
git checkout <sha of merge>
git commit --amend # edit message
git rebase HEAD previous_branch
```

This three lines of code did the job for changing the merge commit message (like author).

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfect. I made 2 commits, realized I didn't set the correct author info before doing so. Reverted the last commit simply by using `git commit --amend --author="Author <new@email.com>" and the followed these steps to fix the one before it.

Answer (score 8):

***Optional*:** Make sure to stash your local changes if you don't want to send them to remote.

```
git status
git stash
```

### Update the author for the last commit.

```
git log   // Old author in local and remote
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
git log   // New Author in local
git push origin <branch> --force-with-lease
git log   // New Author in remote
```

Then, if you used `git stash` then recovers your staged changes

```
git stash pop
git status
```

---

Then, you should to update the configuration for the next commits of the current project.

```
git config user.name "Author Name"
git config user.email "<email@address.com>"
```

And check or also edit this with `git config --edit`

---

*Clarification:* In the rare case that you lose commits using `ggpush -f`, you can recover them with [reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63491854/5279996). Anyway, using `--force-with-lease` you are protected even more than if you use only `-f`

GL

- [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37460330/5279996)
- [Z shell (executable `zsh`)](https://ohmyz.sh/)

Comment: Downvoted because if there is a way to do something without git push -f, then do it without git push -f.

Comment: @Seth There I updated my answer using --with-lease. In what way do you refer anyway? I will try to optimize the commands. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 8):

It could happen if you're missing settings on your machine, e.g., after a format, or when not having a Git configured correctly without setting up (correctly) these commands.

```
git config user.name "Author Name"
git config user.email "<email@address.com>"
```

Why not make your life simpler by following [this article by Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-do-you-make-changes-on-a-specific-commit-779171729.html)?

1. `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"`
2. Unprotect your branch, if it's protected. In this example, it's `master`; therefore, it'll be protected by the source code repository
3. `git push origin master --force`

That's the simplest scenario for the last commit. For picking up any "random" commit, you need:

1. `git rebase -i <Earlier Commit>.`
2. Change `pick` on `edit` on that commit, in which you're interested in
3. `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"`
4. Unprotect your branch if it's protected. In this example, it's `master`; therefore, it'll be protected by the source code repository
5. `git push origin master --force`

You can always `git log` in between to be sure where you are before you push.

Answer (score 7):

Steps to rename author name after commit pushed

1. First type "git log" to get the commit id and more details
2. git rebase i HEAD~10 (10 is the total commit to display on rebase)

   `If you Get anything like below`

   `fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
   I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
   case, please try`

   `git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)`
   `If that is not the case, please rm -fr 
   ".git/rebase-merge"
   and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
   valuable there.`
3. Then type "git rebase --continue" or "git rebase --abort" as per your need

   - now your will rebase window opened, click "i" key from keyboard
   - then you will get list of commits to 10 [because we have passed 10 commit above]
     Like below

   `pick 897fe9e simplify code a little`

   `pick abb60f9 add new feature`

   `pick dc18f70 bugfix`
4. Now you need to add below command just below of the commit you want to edit, like below

   `pick 897fe9e simplify code a little
   exec git commit --amend --author 'Author Name <author.name@mail.com>'
   pick abb60f9 add new feature
   exec git commit --amend --author 'Author Name <author.name@mail.com>' 
   pick dc18f70 bugfix
   exec git commit --amend --author 'Author Name <author.name@mail.com>'`

   5. That's it, now just press ESC, :wq and you are all set
   6. Then git push origin HEAD:BRANCH NAME -f [please take care of -f Force push]

   like  `git push -f` or `git push origin HEAD: dev -f`

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to [Eugen Konkov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51114838/874161), it is possible to keep the commit/author date. To only modify the author but not the date of the last three commits use

```
git rebase --onto HEAD~3 --exec 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git log -n 1 --format=%aD)" git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit --date="$(git log -n 1 --format=%aD)"' HEAD~3
```

then apply a force push

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a shortcut applicable to the most voted question: using `exec` instead of `edit`.

`exec` allows to run a command on a specified commit.
Using it allows to avoid using `edit`, exiting to a terminal and running the `git` command for each git commit.
This is especially helpful if you have to change multiple commits in the history.

The steps are:

1. perform a rebase to an earlier commit (`git rebase -i <earliercommit>`)
2. in the editor that opens up, add a line after each commit line you want to edit and add `exec git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>" --no-edit` (or using `--reset-author` if you want to reset to the value set in the git config)
3. save and exit - this will run the specified command for each commit, effectively changing the author

Example editor content (to change first 2 commits author):

```
pick 1fc6c95 Patch A
exec git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>" --no-edit
pick 6b2481b Patch B
exec git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>" --no-edit
pick dd1475d something I want to split
pick c619268 A fix for Patch B
pick fa39187 something to add to patch A
pick 4ca2acc i cant' typ goods
pick 7b36971 something to move before patch B

# Rebase 41a72e6..7b36971 onto 41a72e6
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use these commands from official page of github

https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-author-info

here is the commands

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

here u can change the old email to ur new user name and email address.

Answer (score 4):

One important thing to mention especially if you are deleting author information for privacy.

After operations from the previous answers:

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
git push -f
```

The commits with old author information **still exist in the Git local and remote cache**.

As GitHub, you can still access the commit by [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), with a warning "This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository."

Garbage collect can be executed within the local repository:

```
git gc
```

However, for GitHub, which you cannot trigger this command, go to *Support*, *[How can we help with removing data from a repository you own?](https://support.github.com/request/remove-data)*, and submit a <kbd>Clear Cached Views</kbd> ticket on your repository.

This last step is applied to ***all*** commit modify/remove operations.

Ref: *[Fully removing the data from GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#fully-removing-the-data-from-github)*

> Warning: This article tells you how to make commits with sensitive data unreachable from any branches or tags in your repository on GitHub.com. However, those commits may still be accessible in any clones or forks of your repository, directly via their SHA-1 hashes in cached views on GitHub, and through any pull requests that reference them. You cannot remove sensitive data from other users' clones of your repository, but you can permanently remove cached views and references to the sensitive data in pull requests on GitHub by contacting GitHub Support.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a lazy approach to this problem, especially if you have more than one commit that you want to change. In my case, I had a new branch with several commits with a wrong author, so what helped me:

**Go to your original branch:**

```
git checkout develop
```

**Create new branch from it:**

```
git checkout -b myFeature develop
```

**Merge it without commit info as one commit:**

```
git merge --no-commit --squash branchWrongAuthor
```

**You might also want to stage changes:**

```
git stage .
```

**Change the name of the author and commit changes:**

```
git commit --amend --author "New Author Name <New Author Email>" -m "new feature added"
```

**And that's it, you can push the changes.**

```
git push
```

You can delete the branch with a wrong author after that.

Answer (score 3):

*Changing Your Committer Name & Email Globally:*

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email "john@doe.org"
```

*Changing Your Committer Name & Email per Repository:*

```
$ git config user.name "John Doe"
$ git config user.email "john@doe.org"
```

*Changing the Author Information Just for the Next Commit:*

```
$ git commit --author="John Doe <john@doe.org>"
```

**Hint**: For other situation and read more information read [the post reference](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email).

Answer (score 2):

The [preferred answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042512/4772994), the one using `git rebase -i` is efficient, but as highlighted in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845565/4772994), it becomes messy when there are merges around the commits to edit. And the use of `git replace` is smart but `git filter-branch` rewrites all the history of other branches and tags, which is not what we want in general.

I wanted to share an alternative to the first answer that remains easy even when there are merges. In my case, when I used `git rebase -i <earlier-commit>`, I got a conflict to solve first, before proceeding with the rebase. In fact, it is easier to use the **break** command rather than the **edit** one. And directly rebase on the commit we target.

Let's take an example and let's assume `git log` shows...

```bash
commit a12afg
...
commit dloe7a
...
commit gh7ag1
...   
commit qp3zaa
...
```

And let's say you want to update the author, message or commit signature for the commit `gh7ag1`. You can proceed with `git rebase -i gh7ag1`. In you editor, you will see:

```
pick dloe7a
pick a12afg
```

Just add a break command:

```
break
pick dloe7a
pick a12afg
```

Save (`:wq` with VI, `Ctrl+O` then `Ctrl+X` with nano).
And now, you are back right after your commit. You can run `git commit --amend` to update the author, the message or the signature (e.g. `git commit --amend -S --author="Your Name <your-email>"`). Verify with `git log --show-signature`. If correct, you can go on with `git rebase --continue`.

And you can have as many **break** commands in the rebase. The continue will move to the next break, if there is one, or apply the remaining commits (provided they are marked as `pick`).

Answer (score 0):

If what you need to change is the AUTHOR OF THE LAST commit and no other is using your repository, you may undo your last commit with:

```
git push -f origin last_commit_hash:branch_name
```

change the author name of your commit with:

```
git commit --amend --author "type new author here"
```

Exit the editor that opens and push again your code:

```
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the author for all commits that were committed by a certain author all at once:

Run the following command to iterate through all commits and update the author information according to the provided conditions:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "Older Author Email" ]; then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="New Author Name"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="New Author Email""
fi
' -- --all
```

Then forcefully push the branch.

```
git push --force origin branch-name
```

Comment: There's no point to using git-filter-branch(1) in current year. See section “Warning” on the man page.

Answer (score 0):

For those curious, I manage to encapsulate the essential logic of [**the leading answer using `git replace`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845565/10237506) into a helper function compatible with `bash`, `zsh`, and other shells.

I created [**a gist**](https://gist.github.com/rnag/9b9f22bc9ccb3be1833fbc5d1b24a342) where you can view it as well.

---

The below function `cca` (shorthand for **change-commit-author**) makes some assumptions:

- The branch with commit(s) to update author for is the *current branch*.
- Git User / Email (AKA *New Author*) is the one currently set up with `git`.
- One of the following arguments is passed in:

  - **Email**, to rewrite author of all commits under that email.
  - Space-separated list of Git **Commit SHA(s)**, to change the author of.
- Git [commit signature verification](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification) is desired, and SSH/GPG keys are set up for that purpose ([**I made a script for this**](https://github.com/rnag/Mac-Quickstart) in case it is helpful).

> ***[!WARNING]***
> Do not use in the `main` branch of shared or published projects without confirming
> with other collaborators beforehand.
>
> The reason is this script performs some "destructive" actions:
>
> - It rewrites *all* commit history, so if someone is working on a dev branch, they will have to rebase or else merge the changes of your branch into theirs.
> - If other collaborators and authors use [commit signature verification](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification) as outlined above, their commits will likely say "**Verified**".
>   After running this script, *all* commits by other authors will say
>   "**Unverified**" -- since the script effectively "rewrites" commit history -- and they will need to run a script to
>   batch re-sign all their previous commits, which will likely
>   rewrite commit history again when changes are pushed.

---

```bash
# Bash/Zsh Function to Change Author for Commit(s)
#
# Adapted from:
#
#   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845565/10237506
#   - https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/user/github/using-git/changing-author-info
#
# Directions:
#
#    Enter either an *Email* to rewrite author of all commits by that email,
#    or a space-separated list of *Git Commit SHA(s)* to change the author of.
#
#    Examples:
#        cca old@email.org
#        cca sha-1 sha-2
#
#   To find Commit SHAs for a Git User with email `current@email.org`, use:
#
#       $ git --no-pager log --format=format:%H --author='current@email.org'
#
#   Alternatively, navigate to below link (substituting org, repo,
#   and Git author) and then *Click "Copy"*
#
#       https://github.com/ORG/REPO/commits?author=AUTHOR
#
function cca() {
    NUM_ARGS=$#

    if [ $NUM_ARGS -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 <AUTHOR_EMAIL_OR_COMMIT_SHA_LIST...>"
        echo
        echo "Bash/Zsh Function to Change Author for Commit(s)"
        echo
        echo Function requires one or more arguments.
        echo
        echo Enter either an email to rewrite author of all commits by that email,
        echo "or a space-separated list of Git Commit SHA(s) to change the author of."
        echo
        echo Examples:
        echo "  $ $0 old@email.org"
        echo "  $ $0 abc123 xyz321"
        echo
        echo To find all Commit SHAs for a Git User with email \`current@email.org\`, use:
        echo "  $ git --no-pager log --format=format:%H --author='current@email.org'"
        return 1
    fi

    # Current Branch
    GIT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    GIT_NAME=$(git config --get user.name)
    GIT_EMAIL=$(git config --get user.email)

    echo "Branch:      ${GIT_BRANCH}"
    echo "Name:        ${GIT_NAME}"
    echo "Email:       ${GIT_EMAIL}"

    # Fix for error message from `git filter-branch`:
    #   Cannot create a new backup.
    #   A previous backup already exists in refs/original/
    #   Force overwriting the backup with -f
    #
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7654880/10237506
    git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d

    # Check for ONE argument, and that the argument is an EMAIL
    # Partial Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4501833/10237506
    if [[ $NUM_ARGS -eq 1 && "$1" =~ .+@.+ ]]; then

        GIT_OLD_EMAIL="$1"

        echo "Old Email:   ${GIT_OLD_EMAIL}"
        echo '[ Replacing Commit Author - Old Email > Email ]'

        # To change the name and/or email address recorded in existing commits,
        # you must rewrite the entire history of your Git repository.
        #
        # Credits: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/user/github/using-git/changing-author-info
        FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 \
            GIT_OLD_EMAIL="$GIT_OLD_EMAIL" \
            GIT_NAME="$GIT_NAME" \
            GIT_EMAIL="$GIT_EMAIL" \
            git filter-branch --env-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$GIT_OLD_EMAIL" ]
        then
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_NAME"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_EMAIL"
        fi
        if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$GIT_OLD_EMAIL" ]
        then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$GIT_NAME"
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$GIT_EMAIL"
        fi
        ' \
            --commit-filter '
        if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$GIT_NAME" || "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$GIT_EMAIL" ]]
        then
        git commit-tree -S "$@";
        fi        
        ' \
            --tag-name-filter cat \
            -- --branches --tags

    else

        # Checkout the commit we are trying to modify
        #
        # The `-c advice.detachedHead=false` parameter will allow you to suppress the warning.
        # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45652159/10237506

        for GIT_COMMIT_SHA in "$@"; do

            git -c advice.detachedHead=false checkout "${GIT_COMMIT_SHA}"

            # Make the author change (use `--no-edit` to skip prompt to update commit message)
            #
            # Update to use `--reset-author` as mentioned in below, so we can also
            # set Git committer instead of just the author. Also, use existing committed date.
            #
            # Refs:
            #   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856838/10237506
            #   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61217637/10237506
            git \
                -c user.name="${GIT_NAME}" \
                -c user.email="${GIT_EMAIL}" \
                commit -S \
                --amend \
                --reset-author \
                --no-edit \
                --date="$(git --no-pager log -1 --format='%aD')"

            GIT_NEW_COMMIT_SHA=$(git --no-pager log -1 --format="%H")

            # Checkout the original branch
            git checkout "${GIT_BRANCH}"

            echo "Commit SHA:        ${GIT_COMMIT_SHA}"
            echo "Commit SHA (NEW):  ${GIT_NEW_COMMIT_SHA}"

            # Replace the old commit with the new one locally
            git replace "${GIT_COMMIT_SHA}" "${GIT_NEW_COMMIT_SHA}"

        done

        # Rewrite all commits based on the replacement
        #
        # Also, sign the commits authored by this user if possible,
        # and correct committer date for rewritten commit above.
        #
        # Refs:
        #   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41883164/10237506
        #   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24820045/10237506

        FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 \
            GIT_NAME=$GIT_NAME \
            GIT_EMAIL=$GIT_EMAIL \
            git filter-branch \
            --env-filter \
            'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"' \
            --commit-filter '
        if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$GIT_NAME" || "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$GIT_EMAIL" ]]
        then
        git commit-tree -S "$@";
        else
        git commit-tree "$@";
        fi
        ' \
            -- --all

        # Remove the replacement for cleanliness
        for GIT_COMMIT_SHA in "$@"; do
            git replace -d "${GIT_COMMIT_SHA}"
        done

    fi

    # Seems to be needed for `--force-with-lease` to work!
    git fetch

    # Push the new history
    if ! git push --force-with-lease; then
        # Only use `--force` instead of `--force-with-lease`
        # if the latter fails, and only after sanity checking
        # with git log and/or git diff.
        echo 'Git Push with `--force-with-lease` failed.'
        # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741036/10237506
        if git diff --exit-code && [[ -z $(git status -uno --porcelain) ]]; then
            echo Git Status/Diff - OK
            N=5
            echo [ Git Log - Showing Top ${N} Commits ]
            git --no-pager log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit -n ${N}
            echo

            # Confirm w/ user to use `--force` for `git push`
            printf '%s' 'Proceed with `git push --force`? [y/N] '

            # Read Character, compatible with `zsh` and `bash`
            # https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022297/10237506
            read_char() {
                stty -icanon -echo
                eval "$1=\$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)"
                stty icanon echo
            }

            read_char REPLY

            echo "$REPLY" # (optional) move to a new line
            if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
                git push -f
                echo 'Git Push with `--force` successful!'
            fi
        else
            echo Git Status/Diff - ERROR, aborting.
            return 1
        fi
    else
        echo 'Git Push with `--force-with-lease` successful!'
    fi
}
```

---

Steps:

1. Open `~/.zshrc` (or `~/.bashrc` for Bash), and paste in the function definition above.
2. Use `source ~/.zshrc` to reload changes into current shell session.
3. Enter either an *Email* to rewrite author of all commits by that email, or a space-separated list of *Git Commit SHA(s)* to change the author of.

   Examples:

   ```
   cca old@email.org
   cca sha-1 sha-2
   ```

   To find Commit SHAs for a Git User with email `current@email.org`, use:

   ```
   $ git --no-pager log --format=format:%H --author='current@email.org'
   ```

   Alternatively, navigate to below link (substituting org, repo,
   and Git author) and then *Click "Copy"*

   ```
    https://github.com/ORG/REPO/commits?author=AUTHOR
   ```

> **N.B.** If `git push --force-with-lease` fails, the function automatically checks status of `git diff` and `git status` to confirm everything is OK.
>
> It then prints the most recent commits from `git log`, then ultimately prompts user to continue with `git push --force` -- which even the linked answer notes, should be used with caution here.
>
> In most of my cases, without `git fetch` it would fallback to `git push -f`, as using `--force-with-lease` never worked otherwise ):