# don't fail jenkins build if execute shell fails

Tags: linux, unix, jenkins

As part of my build process, I am running a git commit as an execute shell step.  However, if there are no changes in the workspace, Jenkins is failing the build. This is because git is returning an error code when there are no changes to commit.  I'd like to either abort the build, or just mark it as unstable if this is the case.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check if there is anything to commit, and only commit in those cases?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139290/how-to-check-if-theres-nothing-to-be-committed-in-the-current-branch

Comment: In a [Pipeline job](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step), if you want `sh` step to continue on failure use `returnStatus: true` (the exit code is returned if you need to evaluate it).

Answer (score 281, accepted):

To stop further execution when *command* fails:

`command || exit 0`

To continue execution when *command* fails:

`command || true`

Comment: You don't need the `|| exit 0` in the first case, if `command` returns false the execution will stop. That said, the second option is very helpful!

Comment: @alfasin You don't understand the problem. OP doesn't want the Jenkins build to fail; ergo we must `exit 0` because any non-zero exit code will fail the build.

Comment: I see, in that case I would change the wording from: "To stop further execution when command fails:" to: "To stop further execution when command fails and mark Jenkins job as successful:".

Comment: Let's keep it professional please. You wrote: " it doesn't mark a job as successful" - I disagree: when you're doing `command || exit 0` - if the command failed - it will *indeed* stop further execution, but it will also mark the job as successful.

Comment: @alfasin  While I agree that Quolonel Questions snappy remark was unprofessional, he was right in what he said. "exit 0" will NOT mark the job successful. It will just mark the current build step successful. The job can still fail on one of the next build steps.

Comment: @noamik you're right! I was dealing with jobs with only one step of "execute shell" hence the misunderstanding. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: This is the fastest and easiest way of not having Jenkins fail a complete build, in other words, a non-critical build step, so you have my +1. 
It is actually really stupid that Jenkins does not offer this functionality by default. Good defaults are one thing, offering good alternatives (OOTB) another.

Comment: Thanks this worked! This is especially useful for the "Execute shell on remote host using ssh" plugin feature since you are not able to use /bin/bash +e to not fail on error. I also like the idea I get to choose which commands don't fail the build.

Comment: Please clarify the "command || other" part goes inside the argument that's passed to the shell, i.e. it should be `sh "command || true"`, not `sh "command" || true`.

Answer (score 109):

Jenkins is executing shell build steps using `/bin/sh -xe` by default. `-x` means to print every command executed. `-e` means to exit with failure if any of the commands in the script failed.

So I think what happened in your case is your git command exit with 1, and because of the default `-e` param, the shell picks up the non-0 exit code, ignores the rest of the script and marks the step as a failure. We can confirm this if you can post your build step script here.

If that's the case, you can try to put `#!/bin/sh` so that the script will be executed without option; or do a `set +e` or anything similar on top of the build step to override this behavior.

---

Edited: Another thing to note is that, if the **last command** in your shell script **returns non-0 code**, the whole build step will still be marked as fail even with this setup. In this case, you can simply put a `true` command at the end to avoid that.

[Another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22816074/2841265)

Comment: This actually solved my problem with Jenkins failing even when trying to suppress errors with `2>/dev/null`. Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

If there is nothing to push git returns exit status 1. Execute shell build step is marked as failed respectively. You can use OR statement || (double pipe).

```
git commit -m 'some messasge' || echo 'Commit failed. There is probably nothing to commit.'
```

That means, execute second argument if first failed (returned exit status > 0). Second command always returns 0. When there is nothing to push (exit status 1 -> execute second command) echo will return 0 and build step continues.

To mark build as unstable you can use post-build step Jenkins Text Finder. It can go through console output, match pattern (your echo) and mark build as unstable.

Answer (score 33):

There is another smooth way to tell Jenkins not to fail. 
You can isolate your commit in a build step and set the shell to not fail:

```
set +e
git commit -m "Bla."
set -e
```

Comment: Make sure to add `set -e` after the command that you want to run irrespective of exit code. Otherwise, you may end up executing commands you don't intend to. I wanted to handle the error myself, so I did something like:
`
  set +e
  commit -m "bla"
  EXIT_CODE="${?}"
  set -e
  # handle exit code logic
`

Answer (score 22):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25745593/1015595) is correct, but it doesn't specify the `|| exit 0` or `|| true` goes *inside the shell command*. Here's a more complete example:

```
sh "adb uninstall com.example.app || true"
```

The above will work, but the following will fail:

```
sh "adb uninstall com.example.app" || true
```

Perhaps it's obvious to others, but I wasted a lot of time before I realized this.

Answer (score 14):

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script

if you include a returnStatus: true property, then the shell return is ignored.

Comment: this is the real answer, a full example would look like: `def rc = sh(script: "git commit", returnStatus: true) ; echo "git commit return code was: ${rc} moving on"`

Answer (score 10):

I was able to get this working using the answer found here:

[How to git commit nothing without an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123674/how-to-git-commit-nothing-without-an-error)

```
git diff --quiet --exit-code --cached || git commit -m 'bla'
```

Comment: What the above does is: "Do `git diff` command, and if that fails, do `git commit` command. Basically, it only does the commit, if the `git diff` found something to commit. However @jwernerny answer was correct that you should be able to add `exit 0` as the last statement to any script to make Jenkins treat it as success. I can think of one scenario where this would fail if you were doing Linux shell step, but in Batch this should always work.

Comment: @Ben Jenkins is executing shell build steps using `/bin/sh -xe` by default as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22816074/2841265) (in the middle). So you can try to put `#!/bin/bash` or do a `set +e` on top of the build step to override this behavior, which will continue the rest of the step even one command inside exit with non-0 code

Answer (score 8):

Jenkins determines the success/failure of a step by the return value of the step.  For the case of a shell, it should be the return of the last value.  For both Windows CMD and (POSIX) Bash shells, you should be able to set the return value manually by using `exit 0` as the last command.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for an 'execute windows bat' that has 2 lines:

git commit -m "message"
exit 0

Comment: @Ben I use `exit 0` with "execute windows batch command" in multiple builds on my Windows Jenkins install, and it works as expected.  Something else must be going on. Could you post the relevant part of the console log?

Comment: are you using it with git commit -m "blah" in your first step?  I tried creating a bat script on the machine manually, and put an echo and an exit 0 after the git command.  Neither of the other commands are run when there is nothing to commit...

Comment: See answer from @xiawei. The default behavior of Jenkins it to execute a shell with `#!/bin/sh -xv` which results in stopping the script if any error is encountered.

Answer (score 8):

On the (more general) question in title - to prevent Jenkins from failing you can prevent it from seeing exit code 1. Example for ping:

```
bash -c "ping 1.2.3.9999 -c 1; exit 0"
```

And now you can e.g. get output of ping:

```
output=`bash -c "ping 1.2.3.9999 -c 1; exit 0"`
```

Of course instead of `ping ...` You can use any command(s) - including `git commit`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Text-finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin). It will allow you to check the output console for an expression of your choice then mark the build as `Unstable`.

Comment: this looked promising, but for some reason it kept failing the build.

Answer (score 6):

For multiple shell commands, I ignores the failures by adding:

`set +e
commands
true`

[image]

Comment: I discourage unsetting -e in general.  If you want to ignore some specific command's return value, you can add "|| true" or something more meaningful returning true, such as: 

stop-service.sh || echo Service was already down

Answer (score 4):

If you put this commands into shell block:

```
false
true
```

your build will be marked as fail ( at least 1 non-zero exit code ), so you can add (set +e) to ignore it:

```
set +e
false
true
```

will not fail. However, this will fail even with the (set +e) in place:

```
set +e
false
```

because the last shell command must exit with 0.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for **mercurial** by only committing if there are changes.  So the build only fails if the commit fails.

```
hg id | grep "+" || exit 0
hg commit -m "scheduled commit"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one answer with some tips, can be helpful for somebody:

remember to separate your commands [with the following rule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37069/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-chaining-commands):

command1 **&&** command2 - means, that command2 will be executed, only if command1 success

command1 **;** command2  - means, that command 2 will be executed despite on result of command1

for example:

```
String run_tests = sh(script: "set +e && cd ~/development/tests/ && gmake test ;set -e;echo 0 ", returnStdout: true).trim()
println run_tests
```

will be executed successfully with `set -e` and `echo 0` commands if `gmake test` failed (your tests failed), while the following code snipped:

```
String run_tests = sh(script: "set +e && cd ~/development/tests/ && gmake test && set -e && echo 0 ", returnStdout: true).trim()
println run_tests
```

a bit wrong and commands `set -e` and `echo 0` in`&& gmake test && set -e && echo 0` will be skipped, with the `println run_tests` statement, because failed `gmake test` will abort the jenkins build. As workaround you can switch to `returnStatus:true`, but then you will miss the output from your command.

Comment: context is everything - and if you don't want to capture console output, then you can even make that sh() function return (instead of failing for a non-0) the status code. sometimes you want both, then you might want to pipe the command outputs to a file - or hope for some simple solution to do so with the status code. ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderStohr true fact! Can't disagree