# Kill all processes on specific port via Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, kill, fuser

I'd like to have a Jenkins job which kills all processes on port 5000 (bash).
The easy solution

```
fuser -k 5000/tcp
```

works fine when I execute this command in the terminal, but on Jenkins ("execute shell") marks build as failure.

I have tried also

```
kill $(lsof -i -t:5000)
```

but again, as it works on regular terminal, on Jenkins I get

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I hadd the same problem. It did not work when the process was not running. `bash` just did it, but jenkins failed.

You can add an `|| true` to your jenkins job to indicate jenkins to proceed with the job if the bash command fails.

So its:

```
fuser -k 5000/tcp || true
```

see also [don't fail jenkins build if execute shell fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392349/dont-fail-jenkins-build-if-execute-shell-fails)

Answer (score 2):

Try put the command with the path

```
/usr/bin/kill $(/usr/sbin/lsof -i -t:5000)
```

If the user running the jenkins service is not the same as the user with the process on port 5000 you won't be able to kill the process. Maybe you will need to run this with sudo.

Try this

```
su -s jenkins #Or the user who run jenkins
/usr/bin/kill $(/usr/sbin/lsof -i -t:5000)
```

Comment: when port 5000 is not exists, jenkins will stop and return fail. How to let it continue to success.

Answer (score 0):

maybe jenkins user can't see the processes because of privileges so the expansion of `$(lsof ..)` is empty.

the error output may not be complete because if lsof call fails there will be a message on stderr.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $ is a special char in jenkins commands. It means you are referring to an ENV VAR.

You should try writing the command wrapped with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and in many cases standard input/output is disabled (specially when you have ssh to the target machine). What you can do is create a executable shell file in the target server and execute that file.

So, the step would look something like below :

Step 1 . -> create the shell file

```
 cat > kill_process.sh << EOF
 target_port_num=\`lsof -i:\${1} -t\`;
 echo "Kill process at port is :: \${target_port_num}"
 kill -9 \${target_port_num}
 EOF
```

Step 2 . -> make it executable
chmod +x process_killer.sh

Step 3 . -> execute the shell and pass the port number
./process_killer.sh 3005

Hope this help.