# Avoid nodejs project build to fail due to eslint error

Tags: node.js, jenkins, eslint, lint, cicd

**Context**

We have a nodejs project which gets built and deployed through Jenkins pipeline. During the build step, it performs `eslint` for all the .js files under a directory and generate eslint report. In case of any eslint error, the Jenkins pipeline fails.

**Problem statement**

We have introduced a sub-directory which contains further .js files. We want to generate eslint report for this, but don't want to fail the pipeline in case of any eslint error.

Can anyone please suggest how can we solve this?

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Does your project use Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how eslint is performed.

With [`gyandeeps/gruntify-eslint`](https://github.com/gyandeeps/gruntify-eslint) task, there is a [silent option](https://github.com/gyandeeps/gruntify-eslint#example-with-silent-option) which allows to *not* fail the job on errors.

In a regular shell step, you can [force the command to not fail with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62646735/6309):

```
sh "<your eslint  command> || true"
```