# List branches not merged to their upstream

Tags: git, branch

I'd like a command similar to `git branch` that will list *all* local branches that are not merged with *their* upstream.

This is something `git branch` knows about, as `git branch -d <branch-name>` will fail for branches that are not merged.

Comment: Probably this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3338774/2303202

Comment: Note that `git branch -d <branch>` succeeds not only if `branch` is merged to its upstream, but also if it's merged to any branch, either local or remote.

Comment: Useful, note, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no single built-in Git command to list all local branches that are behind their upstream branch (if any). However, you can implement the desired functionality using existing Git commands. See below.

## Script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# git-bbu.sh
#
# List the local Branches Behind their Upstream branch, if any.
#
# Usage: git bbu
#
# To make a Git alias called 'bbu' out of this script,
# put the latter on your search path, and run
#
#   git config --global alias.bbu \
#       '!sh git-bbu.sh'

if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    printf "%s\n\n" "usage: git bbu"
    exit 1
fi

git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | \
    while read ref; do
      if (git rev-parse --verify --quiet "$ref"@{upstream} &&
          ! git diff --quiet "$ref"..."$ref"@{upstream}) \
              >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf "%s\n" "$ref"
      fi
    done
```

## Explanation

Run

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads
```

to list all local branches (Why not just use `git branch`, here? Because, in a script, you should try to use plumbing Git commands instead of porcelain ones). Pipe it to a `while` loop, and, for each such local branch,

- Check whether the local branch has an upstream branch, using

  ```
  git rev-parse --verify --quiet "$ref"@{upstream}
  ```
- Check whether the local branch is behind its upstream branch, using (the logical negation of)

  ```
  git diff --quiet "$ref"..."$ref"@{upstream}
  ```

If both conditions are verified, print the name of the branch.

## References

- [gitrevisions man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_revisions)
- [Is there a better way to find out if a local git branch exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167957/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-out-if-a-local-git-branch-exists)
- [How can I programmatically (in a shell script) determine whether or not there are changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772174/how-can-i-programmatically-in-a-shell-script-determine-whether-or-not-there-ar)

Comment: Thanks – I'll give this a try.

Comment: Yes, thank you – it works! Now, I'm wondering if I can get something similar that shows branches that are ahead / behind, and gives the number of commits on each side that need reconciling :-)

Comment: @Benjohn It could be done, but you should probably ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this:

```
git branch --no-merged
```

Above command will list out all the branches which are not merged to your current branch. if you need to check for other branch then

```
git branch --no-merged master
```

You can also compare upstream branches by specifying the -r flag and a ref to check against, which can be local or remote:

```
git branch -r --no-merged origin/master
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773939/show-git-ahead-and-behind-info-for-all-branches-including-remotes) might also be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thank you. No, I don't think I am after this, sorry. I want to see the branches that are not merged with _their_ upstream. As in, those that have something to push to their remote.

Answer (score 0):

`git for-each-ref` has an "upstream" field, which can show if the branch is up-to-date with its upstream. You can then filter its output to show only those which are ahead of their upstreams:

```
$ git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:trackshort)..%(refname:short)' | awk -F '\\.\\.' '$1~/>/{print $2}'
```

this skips branches which do not have upstreams, modify the filter if it's not what you need (the `$1` is empty then in the awk record). `".."` is used a a separator because you cannot have the sequence in reference name

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names