# In VS Code, is there a way to configure source control so that I MUST stage files/changes before they can be committed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-commit

In my current environment, it is possible to accidentally commit *all* changed files at once, without staging. I don't want that to happen.

(Thankfully, that it does happen and I have not yet synced the changes (AKA pushed to remote), [I can just do `git reset HEAD~1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14281090/15994121), and all of the files which were just committed will be back in my staging area).

But how would one prevent all this from happening in the first place? It is super easy to `Ctrl + Enter` and accidentally commit all the files.

Answer (score 3):

VS Code has a feature called "Smart Commits", which is probably what you're running into here.

There are two/three settings of relevance:

1. `git.enableSmartCommit`: "*Commit all changes when there are no staged changes.*" (default: `false`)
2. `git.suggestSmartCommit`: "*Suggests to enable smart commit (commit all changes when there are no staged changes).*" (default: `true`)

Probably what you want is to do is to keep `git.enableSmartCommit` at its default value of `false` (I.e. don't allow commits when nothing has been manually staged for commit) and set `git.suggestSmartCommit` to `false` (I.e. don't ever prompt to change `git.enableSmartCommit` to `true` when attempting to commit before anything has been manually staged).

Once you do that, the next time you try to perform a commit action in VS Code without any staged changes, you'll get a notification saying "*There are no changes to commit. Source: Git (Extension)*", with a button allowing you to "Create Empty Commit" (if you want to).

---

Note that there's also a `git.smartCommitChanges` setting, but it isn't relevant here, since you don't want the smart commit feature, and it's really only relevant when you *do* want the smart commit feature. But for informational purposes:

`git.smartCommitChanges`: "*Control which changes are automatically staged by Smart Commit.*" values:

1. `"all"`: "*Automatically stage all changes.*" (default)
2. `"tracked"`: "*Automatically stage tracked changes only.*"

---

Matt Bierner (one of the VS Code maintainers) has made an explanatory video about the "Smart Commit" feature [here](https://youtu.be/1F48hKFNlg8).

If you like reading about tool history, see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_action-button-improvements.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not the default behavior of VSCode, you probably have `"git.enableSmartCommit": true` in your local settings.

---

You can disable this setting (edit your local `settings.json` or open the UI editor) and either let the GUI guide you -- you should have a dialog popping when you `Ctrl+Enter` with no staged file:

```
There are no staged changes to commit.
Would you like to stage all your changes and commit them directly ?
                                 [Never] [Always] [Cancel] [Yes]
```

or directly set `"git.suggestSmartCommit": false` if your intention is to say `[Never]`.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a `pre-commit` script for git in your project. That way even if you try to commit it will prevent you, as your changes are not staged yet.

Check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76246507/11411002