# Delete Github branches after a certain date

Tags: git, shell

I'm cleaning up a repo that has years of old brnaches. I've found this script to delete after a current week.

for k in $(git branch | sed /*/d); do
if [ -z "$(git log -1 --before='1 week ago' -s $k)" ]; then
git branch -D $k
fi
done

I was curious if this "1 week ago" could be altered to a specific date (i.e. April 21 2023) and it's format.

I was also curious if a condition could be added to see if it has differences from develop/main to ignore deleting that branch.

Comment: Regarding differences between develop/main: `git branch --no-merge <targetBranch>` - this will show all the branches that have not been merged to a target branch. I don't think deleting based on date is a good approach, if branch is already merged to the mainline, it can be deleted immediately.

Comment: @Ryan the purpose of deleting is simply because I have years of branches that haven't been updated in quite a while and want to clean up my repo. Just seeing if they are different from develop/main still requires a lot of manual effort to go thru and clean it all up.

Comment: Use `--merge` option for command above to find and delete them all in one run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the `1 week ago` to a specific date.  This answer should help with the different formats that you are allowed to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742762/498699

The -D option will always delete the branch.  Use the `-d` if you want to ensure that you don't lose unmerged changes. If you want to compare to a different branch to prevent delete.  This answer has some guidance https://stackoverflow.com/a/28772375/498699 You can use the `--quiet` option and the `||` operator to only run the delete command if there are differences between the two branches

You would be able to change the command to:

```
for k in $(git branch | sed /*/d); do if [ -z "$(git log -1 --before='1 week ago' -s $k)" ]; then git diff --quiet <other branch> || git branch -D $k fi done
```

Comment: `The -D option only deletes the branch if it hasn't been fully merged` You mean `-d` here, not `-D`. From manual page: `-D: Shortcut for --delete --force ... --force: ... In combination with -d (or --delete), allow deleting the branch irrespective of its merged status`.

Comment: No, I meant -D but my explanation was the exact opposite of what I meant.  Using -D would prevent the delete if there are changes on the branch wanting to be deleted since it wouldn't be fully merged.  Updated

Comment: So to clarify the other comments, -D would only delete if the branch has been merged into develop/main branch. -d would delete the branch regardless of it's been merged? Also, the || on the left side just leaves the branch alone if it's difference then develop & on the right it'll delete it if it's been merged?

Comment: Also, to combine it with the relative date you posted, I'd change the ```--before='1 week ago'``` to something like ```--date=format:relative:3.months.ago```?

Comment: @JustThatGuy93 use the -d for prevent the deletion for the main branch.  The || would be for comparing against other branches (rather than master).