# Shell - Exit a while on keypress

Tags: bash, shell

On a Raspberry, I made a custom slideshow with movies and pictures. I am expanding the script so I can also choose a clip to play if necessary. I made a menu with 3 options:

1. Slideshow
2. Clips
3. Shutdown

The Slideshow is an infinite loop:

```
case $opt in
            "Slideshow")
            PLAY="1"
            while true; do
                    if [ "$PLAY" = "1" ];
                    then
                            PLAY=2
                            bash ./videoplayer.sh
                    else
                            PLAY=1
                            bash ./pictureplayer.sh
                    fi
            done
            ;;
```

The example of videoplayer.sh:

```
VIDEOPATH="/home/pi/ftp/video"

for entry in $VIDEOPATH/*
do
        clear
        omxplayer "$entry" > /dev/null
done
```

The example of pictureplayer.sh:

```
PICTUREPATH="/home/pi/ftp/picture"

fbi -a --noverbose -t 30 -u -1 $PICTUREPATH/*.png
```

At any given moment I would like to stop the while loop and show the menu again. Even if it is in the middle of a clip playing. I only found options that can read an input after or before every play of a clip/picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues: stopping the clip and, if you want instant response, [accepting keys instead of input lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725925/how-to-read-just-a-single-character-in-shell-script).  Run the slideshow in the background and then kill it after the `read` returns:

```
case $opt in
            "Slideshow")
            (set -m             # set up process groups
             ./slideshow.sh &   # the existing loop
             read -n1
             kill -HUP %+)      # subshell suppresses signal reporting
            ;;
```

The one `kill` affects all the processes ([demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yuCyZd6op0aBRF9Q)) because a shell with job control (`-m`) enabled puts them all in a process group.  (Note that you don't have to put `bash` in front of a shell script name if you give the file a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and make it executable.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to search a bit. From what I found and tried so far this option works: I added a new option 3)  Exit Current Play and did a pkill -f slideshow.sh, pkill -f videoplayer.sh and a pkill -f omxplayer. I added in the first option a "&" after bash ./slideshow.sh.

Comment: I added a bit more text as an alternative to the above (which may very well work).

Comment: I added the new code in the original post. The last code you gave me didn't work like it supposed to. it didn't stop the script. I got a new small problem now, it's stated in the original post.

Comment: @ErXoR: You should probably ask a new question rather than editing this one into being altogether different.  But what do you mean by the generic "didn't work"?

Comment: Will do so, I will remove the editing in the first post. The code that you gave (read -n1 and kill -HUP $!) doesn't stop the slideshow. It just keeps going. The pkill -f command works in this case. Could it be that it keeps going because I'm not putting the commands directly into the terminal, but through ssh?

Comment: @ErXoR: Sorry: I misread the very manual page I linked to!  The correct answer is to use process groups (partly because it avoids needing to know the names of the subprocesses); I've edited the answer.