# How can I read a single char from stdin without invoking bash?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, stdin, dd

I am trying to read a single char from stdin inside a shell script (not a bash-script).

I  have a script with the following line:

```
#!/bin/sh

…

char=$(/bin/bash -c 'read -s -n1 key; echo "$key"')

…
```

This works (assuming bash is installed), but it feels kinda wrong to have that line of code.

Is there a better more portable way to do it?

---

It should work cross-platform, but even with the few platforms I tested it on (debian, maemo, cygwin, fedora), I could not find a way to do it without having bash installed and invoking an instance of bash just to read one keystroke.

I also tried `char="$(dd bs=1 count=1)"` but dd only returns/exits after a newline/EOF.

---

*Duplicate*

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725925/how-to-read-just-a-single-character-in-shell-script) has answers that work for my problem.

This might not be an exact duplicate because:

1. That question is only about ksh.
2. The top voted answer is only repeating my problem: "How to do it with bash"

But it was asked and answered, because the [excepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732057/10822366) and the [best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022297/10822366) answer, both work cross platform. The answer I named "best" does it better ;)

Comment: Isn't `read` builtin part of POSIX shell as well? All options may not work though

Comment: @anubhava Exactly: The `-n` option "returns after reading nchars" is neither POSIX nor is it supported by `dash` or `ash` (sometimes some non-POSIX still works cross platform, sadly not in this case)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725925/how-to-read-just-a-single-character-in-shell-script

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Thanks. Just tested [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022297/10822366) with dash and ash. IMHO my question can be closed as a duplicate. Gonna add a comment "it also works with dash/ash" to the answer as soon as I am allowed to do so.