# Git rebase change author?

Tags: git

So I stupidly made 3 commits on a machine that was not configured for git (no author or email) and I want to change those 3 commits (have not been pushed) authors to what they are suppose to be.

I know `git commit --amend` can change the author, but how can I do it to 3? I know rebase can change the message. Is there a way to change author?

Comment: In case others don't see the duplicate message at the top like me, the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320317/292408

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The flagged question targets *multiple* commits, while this question only targets the use of rebase.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can use interactive rebase. The answer from this post gives you an example:
[How to change the commit author for one specific commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit).

In particular, you can do the following to change one specific commit:

`git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>" --no-edit`

The author asks for changing author at a specific commit, but interactive rebasing can be used to change authors of multiple commits if you `edit` all commits that you wish to change.

Other potential useful techniques related to interactive rebasing could be found in the Pro Git book
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History, including squashing, redordering, editing messages, etc.

Comment: The Pro Git chapter you reference also mentions using `git filter-branch --commit-filer` to do this same thing, but unless you're proficient in bash scripting, it's probably harder to use vs the interactive rebase.

Comment: @ColdHawaiian Thanks for your comment. I was trying to provide a more comprehensive reference to the interactive rebasing tool and should state more clearly.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work. It's not changing the author, just the message

Comment: You should be able to do it all at once with `git rebase BASE_BRANCH --exec 'git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>" --no-edit'`

Comment: Also: please provide context for links https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Note that `git rebase --exec ...` works technically by running the given command after each commit in the rebased branch. The BASE_BRANCH in comment of @DylanYoung should point to latest commit that you don't want to modify. Everything after that in the current branch will be modifed.

Comment: @DylanYoung's command worked perfectly for me! Thank you! (macOS catalina, git v2.32.0)

Comment: `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Author Name" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="author@email.com" git commit --amend --author="authorname <author@email.com>" --no-edit` This gets committer name update too apart from author.

Comment: If you've changed your `user` then you can rebase, and for each commit, execute a `git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit` like this `git rebase --exec 'git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit' BASE`