# Git Error :- expected committer email 'xxx@yyy.com' but found 'bbb@yyy.com'

Tags: git

Hi Iam planning to slice a folder from the existing repo and to move that to another bare repo,
Iam following this [https://gist.github.com/trongthanh/2779392](https://stackoverflow.com) to move the repo, but at the last 'git push' facing the following issue:-

```
$ git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 4203, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4203/4203), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2435/2435), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4203/4203), 250.58 MiB | 277.70 MiB/s, done.
Total 4203 (delta 1720), reused 4202 (delta 1720), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1720/1720), done.
remote: Rejected by YACC
remote:
remote:   (c).-.(c)    (c).-.(c)    (c).-.(c)    (c).-.(c)    (c).-.(c)
remote:    / ._. \      / ._. \      / ._. \      / ._. \      / ._. \
remote:  __\( Y )/__  __\( Y )/__  __\( Y )/__  __\( Y )/__  __\( Y )/__
remote: (_.-/'-'\-._)(_.-/'-'\-._)(_.-/'-'\-._)(_.-/'-'\-._)(_.-/'-'\-._)
remote:    || E ||      || R ||      || R ||      || O ||      || R ||
remote:  _.' `-' '._  _.' `-' '._  _.' `-' '._  _.' `-' '._  _.' `-' '.
remote: (.-./`-'\.-.)(.-./`-`\.-.)(.-./`-`\.-.)(.-./`-'\.-.)(.-./`-`\.-.)
remote:  `-'     `-'  `-'     `-'  `-'     `-'  `-'     `-'  `-'     `-'
remote:
remote:
remote: Push rejected.
remote:
remote: refs/heads/master: 1f77a4445ec: expected committer email 'xxx@yyy.com' but found 'bbb@yyy.com'
remote:
remote: refs/heads/master: be3b4b47d9a: expected committer email 'xxx@yyy.com' but found 'bbb@yyy.com'
```

Have tried

> $ git filter-branch --env-filter '
> OLD_EMAIL="xxx@yyy.com"
> CORRECT_NAME="xxx"
> CORRECT_EMAIL="xxx@yyy.com"
> if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
> then
> export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
> export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
> fi
> if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
> then
> export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
> export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
> fi
> ' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags

and

> git commit --amend --author="xxx xxx@yyy.com" --no-edit

but still have the same error, want to have histories of the files to be preserved, changing the author will change history also? please help on this.

Comment: Remote is using a hook, in which it verifies who is allowed author commits. Apparently your email is not the one. When you just change the email address the commits will not be updated. You would need to interactively rebase all commits.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217801/git-rebase-change-author)

Comment: @ValerijDobler, will git history be preserved interactively changing the author, wouldn't the original author of that file be changed?

Comment: Git has two records of who is making changes `Author` and `Committer`. Author is preserved in rebases while Committer will be changed.

Comment: You need to rewrite history. If the dupe doesn't answer your question, let us know

Comment: Hi tried git commit --amend --author="xxx<xxx@yyy.com>" --no-edit still facing the same issue :(

Comment: This probably requires temporarily turning off the policy that enforces people can only push their own commit on the target host.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7988885/7360

Comment: changing the hooks (switching off the YACC) worked, but 'verify committer hook' was already turned off