# How to change author on git commit without re-fixing merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rerere

I am working on a project with git version control. It has many contributors. In the first few days of the project, many commits were made without an author. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit) too. I have tried going through `git rebase -i <Original commit SHA>` but all of the commits I flag with an `edit` tag have merge conflicts to address! I looked into calling `rerere` to use the old fixes, but because `rerere` changes are cached and I had not originally set it to `true` in gitconfig, it's not an option here.

Short of going commit-by-commit and readdressing the merge conflicts, what can I do to change the authors for those early commits?

Comment: If you're doing a rebase that involves merge commits, why aren't you using the `--preserve-merges` flag?

Comment: For merges to show up in rabase command we, need to add `-r` or `rebase-merges`. Then we get knee-deep in some merge-conflicts somewhere again !

Answer (score 1):

The posts your reference mention `rebase -i`, but also [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

You should try the [`git filter_branch` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870367/6309), which doesn't re-apply each commits, and doesn't have to resolve merge conflicts.

Like the rebase, that will change your history, though, and you will have to `push --force` the end result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will help this parameter `--author`.
So if yo have merge commit already just whrite:

```
git commit --amend --author="Foo Bar <foo@example.com>"
```