# How do I change the author of a commit in GIT from specific revision

Tags: git

I have committed some files with wrong author name, when I saw with `git config -l`, it is sawing some other user details and my files were committed under those user details.

Now I want to change author name from existing commit.

I got some POST with ans but they are providing solution which will replace the auther from all commits.

I want to change author from some specific commits only.

Comment: This might have been a better duplicate target: [Change commit author at one specific commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit).

Answer (score 1):

If it's the last commit only use

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Or if you want to change it to something not in your `.gitconfig`

```
git commit --amend --author="Name <email@example.com>"
```

If it's the last couple of commits you can combine this with a `git-rebase`

**NOTE** It's recommended that you don't use this if you already have pushed your work, it will require a force push and will conflict with all the people who are working with you on the project.