# invalid author/committer line - missing space before email

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I have a *git* repository that was cloned from a *bzr* repository using *git-remote-bzr* as follows: `git clone bzr::/repo new-repo`. 
After a few hundreds of commits, I executed `git fsck` and I got the following error for all the *bzr* commits:

> error in commit 41bf5: invalid author/committer line - missing space before email

When I check these revisions with `git cat-file -p 41bf5` I can indeed see that the author name and the email are not separated with a space.

**How can I add this missing space for all the bad commits ?**

I have full access to the repo on the server so I can rewrite the history without any problems. After modifications the users of the code will have to reclone the repository.
I already tried without success the solutions proposed in the following posts:

- [How do I change the author of a commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)
- [Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit?lq=1)

Comment: I don't know off-hand if this will work, but running `git filter-branch` with the `--commit-filter` set to simply run `git commit-tree "$@"` every time seems likely to do the trick.  (If not, maybe `--env-filter` will do it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to my question came from a friend that asked me to write the answer on his behalf:

1. Filter the repo, changing the bogus author with the following. Note that this should be on two separate lines (normally using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

   ```
   $ git filter-branch --commit-filter 'case "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" in
   > *author\<\ email*) GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=author_name; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=author_email;; esac; git commit-tree "$@" '
   ```
2. Since the faulty commits are still in the repository, `git fsck` will still fail on them. To get rid of those commits, clone the repo and then prune unused objects:

   ```
   $ git clone badrepo goodrepo && cd goodrepo
   $ git gc --prune=all
   ```
3. The new repository is clean. `git fsck` returns no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a perfectly working example on [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html). As already mentioned by torek, it uses `git filter-branch` to rewrite all the history affected by your problem.

You will have to change it a bit:

```
$ git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "name_and_email" ];
    then
            GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="name";
            GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="email";
            git commit-tree "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD
```

Not sure whether the $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME will work on the invalid commits, but if it does the above command should do the trick for one author.

---

If all your commits have the problem, you can skip the `if` thing and use a regex or something like that to automatically find the border between name and email. That way you can do it completely automatically for all authors.

Comment: I already tried that code. It does not catch the "name<email>". Not all the commits in the repo have this problem.