# git object have invalid commit data - date

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-remote, unfuddle

I am trying to upload my unfuddle repo to github. I have added github repo by ssh and it is working fine. But when i trying to push data it says invalid object author line. When i push to unfuddle it works fine .

```
remote: error: object 9283f9029b065b6be9d4ecb483e47be8dcce84be:invalid author/co
mmitter line - missing space before date
remote: fatal: Error in object
```

can anyone guide me how to edit the author line /date for this commit object .

EDIT

i checked the details for this commit, and it has unix default date.

```
$ git show 9283f9029b065b6be9d4ecb483e47be8dcce84be
commit 9283f9029b065b6be9d4ecb483e47be8dcce84be
Author: HEMC <HEMC@HEMC-PC>
Date:   Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 +0000
```

I tried to rewrite the date as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git) .

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = 9283f9029b065b6be9d4ecb483e47be8dcce84be ]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Mon May 2 21:38:53 2014 -0800"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon May 19 01:01:01 2014 -0700"
     fi'
```

But it says `Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.`

I tried to drop stash .

```
$ git stash drop
No stash found.
```

I don't know, what is the problem with rewrtit.

Comment: What git version and OS are you using? Last time I saw that error message, the git client was to blame: https://github.com/Sybio/ImageWorkshop/issues/26#issuecomment-28550409

Comment: Likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971941/invalid-author-committer-line-missing-space-before-email

Comment: @centic already check that solution. But i want only for a single commit.

Comment: It sounds like unfuddle exports the git-report in a slightly broken manner here, the exception says that the objects are not well-formed git-format, maybe you need to contact the unfuddle team to fix it on their end?

Comment: @VonC last time i was working on different machine, the post you linked is also mine. Now i ma using windows 7 , my client is  1.8.4.msysgit.0. Some of person in my team may had using old client, but how i can fix it now.

Comment: "Unstaged changes" has nothing to do with the stash. Use `git reset --hard` to _destroy_ (no, there's no backup) all unstaged edits from your working copy. You can of course create a new stash from your changes: `git stash save`, if you do not want to destroy them.