# Invalid author/committer line - bad name

Tags: git, gitlab

I appeal to GitLab forum, because on other repositories with this problem I have.

It's that if I want push repository with cca 27 000 +- commits to gitlab, i get this error message:

```
invalid author/committer line - bad name
```

Git fsck:

```
$ git fsck
error in commit 0d4bbd96410dfa6d9d9bf761f26ba7651da38a96: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 12b631675ee57e6dff9b8a88d701f5fb675124f5: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 7ce2853ca86fd855d1cd91faa8544d3aeecab64d: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit b5342fe7542caea020a89112a93bb963aae132e2: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 4077f525f04109e098c53eccde319b96f3335295: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 1ba710a7bd959908adef4a5d1614efe13e7018d1: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit bd23bd1c5c0607c09d6539edfaa658d12b988261: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 9923df774580cbba6455face1631074105db9bba: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit e316869ee4c99a437249e4d24e0734d05bfbf9ac: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 971d617e9e01640a4f2b6d55aba4d98dfd352a76: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 9629a340c6f8af87d2673ecab6c05d319aac26a5: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit ce1280627d7f075ec7cbd54182089714086f808e: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 2e6ca81365001c564ef7b4e826d79f951b362385: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 848dafd3ac203cdddc312825d5a139f95afe4ba5: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 85d3dc8b719e116d948de66bde26291a8d8c6647: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 7c4f2f520f4047b10d94e44f6af1c910ff4bdbcf: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 3b389b8aa2a4dcf916b1151acde4721f429d6199: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 83500cb1e4388937a98bba1903de37430415ea16: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit 66f5d749c0f72053ddc8f2c9716310102b822f03: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit c5f83416343882ab5a5c1548832dc675e999ad36: invalid author/committer line - bad name
error in commit a32d417cf00ab527f8bfc255c6b2399e855d582d: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 16565316e4a177d152a64a13db14e7c0c8335c2b: invalid author/committer line - bad email
```

I have this problem only on Gitlab, on bitbucket push with no problem.
I need help what can I resolve this problem. I want push to my repository.

Comment: Try "git show ..." on some of those commits to see what the author/committer line looks like.

Comment: $ git show 0d4bbd96410dfa6d9d9bf761f26ba7651da38a96

Author: malcromdev@gmail.com> <none@none>

Date:   Tue May 18 19:08:08 2010 -0230

Comment: I see two `>`-s in the output of your `git show`.  Note also that `git show` by default uses `--format=medium` which shows only the author line, not the committer line.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971941/invalid-author-committer-line-missing-space-before-email

Answer (score 2):

I am 3 and a half years late to this sad party, but maybe you ended up here like I did, finding no answer :)

In my case, I am trying to move a large repository that has a long history, branches, etc.

A long ago some commit had a badly formatted author (something like "Jonh Doe "). That's obviously wrong, but we make mistakes while young, right?

Now gitlab complains about this, rightfully so.

In my case, the option of rewriting the whole history for a mistake done in its (the repository's) childhood is worse than living with that mistake.

So how do we tell gitlab to live with that mistake?
One solution is to disable gitlab's checks by:

1. Edit `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and configure the advanced option that disables git checking of objects when receiving: `omnibus_gitconfig['system'] = { "receive" => ["fsckObjects = false"] }`
2. Reconfigure gitlab: `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

I am aware that this solution might not be acceptable for everyone, but it "Works for Me". Hopefully somebody will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

This check can be bypassed using [GitLab's repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html#pulling-from-a-remote-repository-starter). After the first sync is performed you can disable the mirroring and use the repository as normal.