# git uses root instead of my username while commit linux

Tags: linux, git, github

I have a linux machine running with Git. I did a checkout of a repo and I do commits from the linux commnad line. When I do push and pull operations, it asks me my username and password, and then it shows success.

However, in logs, it shows committed by root. I checked in git config, and I could not find anything.

Here are the values of my config file:

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0 
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/my-username/RepositoryName.git
branch.stage.remote=origin
branch.stage.merge=refs/heads/stage
```

Comment: This is not a programming question. Maybe post it on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Don't worry, [git] questions are welcome on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 12):

You need to set your user.name and your.email

```
git config --global user.name xxx
git config --global user.email xxx@mail.com
```

If you only did one commit, you can amend it:

```
git commit --amend --author "New Author Name <email@address.com>"
```

See more at "[Change the author of a commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/6309)".

If you did several commit, you would need to rewrite those (see "[Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042706/6309)")

Comment: Hi VonC,

Thanks for the reply. But I am not the only person who do commits. Other people will also do pull and push from that same repository... In that case, I cant set my username there.

Comment: Those settings are only for your repo, when logged as you. Others will have their settings

Comment: Note that the even if git config --list has both the user.name and user.email listed, the command in the answer may still be necessary. I think it's the --global flag that makes the difference