# Change the author of last commit in Git(pushed remotely)

Tags: git, github, version-control, push

I am trying to change the author name of last commit.
As mentioned in [Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit), I am executing `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"` command.
In my git log I can see that name and email have been changed.
But when I am executing `git push -f`, it is giving me following error

```
remote: To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected.
! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Any idea how can i push this.

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: Try to update your local branch using `git pull` or `git rebase` first.

Comment: I did. This have latest changes.

Comment: Did you compare remote and local log? You can check remote log via `git log remotename/branchname`. There should be some conflict showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your remote server is preventing the push. You need to (temporarily) configure it to permit pushing non-fast-forward changes for that branch to achieve what you want. How you do that depends on which server you are using; for example, if it's a bare Git repository on a server you can change it with `git config receive.denyNonFastForwards false`.