# Git rebase to previous commit gives wrong list of commits

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I have a history on my repository like so:

[image]

Now I want to fix those 3 commits where my partner did not correctly author it, i've done this before using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit) answer as a guide. So since I want to change those 3, I figured I would rebase at `face866`, so I run

`git rebase -i face866`

But something weird happens, this is the list of commits I am met with

[image]

`fcc7a9b`, `2459b01`, `2f805cd` all make sense, but where is `18bc0ad`? And why are all the commits from 7 days ago skipped? it continues on from the commit from 11 days ago **but**, they all have different tags too?

Even stranger, if I open the repo up in Github's app it says my history is:

[image]

Which is missing commits. What is going on here? The commit list doesn't make any sense to me, and the app has the wrong history. I only have one idea as to what has happened

- Last time I rebased I used `git push --force` to rewrite the history, I was not aware my partner was active and as he has push access, he pushed those commits < 6 days ago with his old history but it didn't seem to double the commits as I expected

EDIT: decorated log
[image]

Comment: Can you run `git fetch` and post the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all --branches -15`?

Comment: @AlexanderGroß Sure, see edit at bottom

Answer (score 2):

`git rebase` will linearize your commit history before your merge commit `18bc0ad`. That is why it is missing. `git rebase` has a `--preserve-merges` switch that you probably know, but I advise [against using it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_bugs).

In your case I'd say it's best to keep the history as-is. From my experience, you would otherwise likely end up in a very painful situation. If you want to try, you can start the rebase and perhaps `git rebase --abort` when there are too many conflicts to resolve.