# Bitbucket need to change last commit author name

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-commit, tortoisegit

I accidentally made some commit on repository with different author name.

Can we change last commit author name on Bitbucket commit history?

Note: I am using git (TortoiseGit) and Bitbucket.

Comment: Check out this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit) .I think this might help.

Comment: Thanks sallu, it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitbucket does not support that, but you can do it locally in your GIT GUI of choice.

For the very last commit this is quite easy. Open the Commit Dialog locally, select "Amend", check "Set author" and then commit and force push.

If the commit is older, you need to rebase. Checkout the branch the commit is on and then right click on the commit before the one you want to change in the log dialog and select "Rebase onto". In the rebase dialog, check force and mark the commit you want to change as "Edit" and start the rebasing process. When the commit is processed, select "Edit/add commit" and update the author name.