# Why cant i see the output of the git commands?

Tags: git

I have **git** installed.
I created a new repository and now I want to add some files to the staging.
But I've faced formatting and whitespace issues while trying to do this.
And I need to run this command now:

```
 $ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

But nothing happens when I press enter. It just returns me to the directory I'm trying to run this command from. No response to my actions at all.

The same problem occurs when I'm running this command:

```
$ git add -A
```

But when I'm running this:

```
$ git init
```

Everything works fine.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its ok,

The 2 command does not print anything in reply. :-)

No feedback on those commands. As you can see no feedback is supplied on those command.

[image]

- If you wish to verify that the config value is set check your `.git/config`
  and in your case since you added `--global` the config entry will be in your `~/.gitconfig`.
- To verify that the `git add` is working - use the `git status` to see the list of added file.

---

### ***`List of help messages generated by GIT:`***

You can turn them on/off with the configuration:

```
# turn the detached message off
git config --global advice.<one of list below> false
```

> ***`advice.*`***
>
> These variables control various optional help messages designed to aid new users. All advice.* variables default to true, and you can tell Git that you do not need help by setting these to false:

You can set any of the following after the advice:

```
git config --global advice.<...>


pushUpdateRejected
    Set this variable to false if you want to disable 
        pushNonFFCurrent,
        pushNonFFMatching, 
        pushAlreadyExists, 
        pushFetchFirst, and 
        pushNeedsForce simultaneously.

pushNonFFCurrent
    Advice shown when git-push(1) fails due to a non-fast-forward update
    to the current branch.

pushNonFFMatching
    Advice shown when you ran git-push(1) and pushed matching refs
    explicitly (i.e. you used :, or specified a refspec that isn’t your
    current branch) and it resulted in a non-fast-forward error.

pushAlreadyExists
    Shown when git-push(1) rejects an update that does not qualify
    for fast-forwarding (e.g., a tag.)

pushFetchFirst
    Shown when git-push(1) rejects an update that tries to overwrite a
    remote ref that points at an object we do not have.

pushNeedsForce
    Shown when git-push(1) rejects an update that tries to overwrite a
    remote ref that points at an object that is not a commit-ish, or make
    the remote ref point at an object that is not a commit-ish.

statusHints
    Show directions on how to proceed from the current state in the output
    of git-status(1), in the template shown when writing commit messages in
    git-commit(1), and in the help message shown by git-checkout(1) when
    switching branch.

statusUoption
    Advise to consider using the -u option to git-status(1) when the command
    takes more than 2 seconds to enumerate untracked files.

commitBeforeMerge
    Advice shown when git-merge(1) refuses to merge to avoid overwriting
    local changes.

resolveConflict
    Advice shown by various commands when conflicts prevent the operation
    from being performed.

implicitIdentity
    Advice on how to set your identity configuration when your information
    is guessed from the system username and domain name.

detachedHead
    Advice shown when you used git-checkout(1) to move to the detach HEAD
    state, to instruct how to create a local branch after the fact.

amWorkDir
    Advice that shows the location of the patch file when git-am(1) fails
    to apply it.

rmHints
    In case of failure in the output of git-rm(1), show directions on
    how to proceed from the current state.
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I don't have much experience with the command line and all commands before was giving me feedback. So it got me confused :)

Comment: Sure. Read this answer to see the full list of the help messages which git display. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794501/disable-warning-about-detached-head/36794768#36794768

Comment: Glad to help. Here is another useful answer - not relevant but you can learn from it something new i assume. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716

Comment: Feel free to vote if you liked it. Appropriated. Takes time to write it :-)