# suppress detached head warning in Bash script

Tags: bash, git

I'm writing a shell script to checkout branches or tags in multiple Git repositories.  Sometimes, the checkout is to move HEAD to a tagged commit which does not have a branch associated with it.  That is intentional, and it causes a detached HEAD state.  While looking for a way to suppress the lengthy detached HEAD warning just for the current script (not in the config), I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794501/disable-warning-about-detached-head).

Here is the attempt I made to incorporate the answer from that thread into my code:

```
# repositories against which to run commands in this script
repos[0]="./sandbox"
repos[1]="./playground"

# branch or tag to checkout in all repos (TODO: change this to a list user selects from)
ref="tags/v1"

# checkout reference in all repos
for i in "${repos[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
    # git -C "$i" checkout "$ref" # <--- this worked to repoint HEAD but got detatched HEAD error
    git -C "$i" checkout "$ref" -c advice.detachedHead=false
done
    
# wait to close terminal until user is ready
read -p "Press Enter to exit terminal"
```

However, this results in the following -

> error: unknown switch 'c'

When the lines in the loop are changed to this:

```
echo "$i"
git -C "$i" -c advice.detachedHead=false
git -C "$i" checkout "$ref"
```

a message appears about the usage of Git (see partial screenshot below) and the detached HEAD message is still present.
[image]

How can this code be modified to suppress the detached HEAD message just for the script?

Comment: Move that up before checkout

Comment: `git -C "$i" -c advice.detachedhead=false checkout $ref`, or save yourself the repetition and `git config --global advice.detachedhead false` once and never be bothered again. `git`'s `-c` option is a one-time override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of flags to `git` matters:

```
git <flag-set-1> <command> <flag-set-2> <arguments>
```

runs `git` with *`flag-set-1`* so that `git` runs *`command`* with *`flag-set-2 arguments`* while obeying *`flag-set-1`*.  The `-c advice.detachedHead=false` argument is an argument to `git`, not to any of the *`command`* commands.  That is, you want:

```
git -C "$path" -c advice.detachedHead=false checkout ...
```

rather than:

```
git -C "$path" checkout -c advice.detachedHead=false ...
```

(The `git clone` command accepts very similar `-c` arguments in its flag-set-2, but don't let that mislead you!)