# Github invalid author email commits, no contribution activity

Tags: git, github

Recently, I did some commits without config user.email. Is there any way to edit those commits to be recognized as contribution on my GitHub profile. (there're no commit email - to add to as GitHub account - as you can see in the log bellow)

Here some recent commit from git log command:

(the last/first one with email is commited after I config user.email)

```
commit 4ae6cc5c00e380c70072f9647b29dc242d2682d1
Author: Tin Nguyen <my-Gmail@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 22 11:00:30 2016 +0700

    delete some unnecessary code

commit 275362c077bb0495318d37b965c90beba2cb79b3
Author: Tin Nguyen <Tin Nguyen>
Date:   Wed Sep 21 07:41:51 2016 +0700

    modify database rules

commit c6b3af19c24627cafd862eff7449bc5d3f95cfbc
Author: Tin Nguyen <Tin Nguyen>
Date:   Sun Sep 18 14:14:23 2016 +0700
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you didn't share your work with someone else (if they didn't pull/clone/fork it yet), you can edit those by doing an interactive rebase, for example:

```
git rebase -i c6b3af19^
# change the comits you want to edit to "e" or "edit", leave the other on "p", "pick"
git commit --amend --author "Tin Nguyen <my-Gmail@gmail.com>"  --no-edit
git rebase --continue
#repeat the two last steps until done
```

Or more complex, but faster (one-liner):

```
git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="my-Gmail@gmail.com"' c6b3af19^..HEAD HEAD
```

Or without using `filter-branch` (note that you must have correctly set your name and mail globally):

```
 git rebase c6b3af19^ --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author'
```

Just be aware that both will overwrite authorship information from `c6b3af19` to the last commit you did, they are incomplete in the case you have other authors who committed more recently.

Note that in every case, you will then have to do a forced push to your remote repository, with `git push -f`

---

In any case, I suggest you to create a new branch before attempting to do this kind of changes. You can also use the reflog to recover if something bad happens, or just `git checkout 4ae6cc5c`, which was your latest commit to date. But as a rule of thumb, I think it is better to branch before doing any history rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your username and email with `git config` and try this:

```
git rebase -i YOUR_COMMIT_SHA -x "git commit --amend --reset-author -CHEAD"
```

It will reset the author for the selected commit.

Answer (score 0):

git rebase and git commit -amend will help you updating user email. [rebase and amend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit)

[update user email](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13755980)

Comment: Make sense. Will do that . Thanks