# Removing <user> committed with <user> on Github

Tags: git, rebase

I have a number of commits on github that look like this:

[image]

Is there a way of rebasing so that I can get rid of this and simply have the commit marked as by me?

Comment: FWIW, I think the problem was caused by using a slightly different v. of my name on two different computers. That or updating my email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would check that your git is configured with the correct user information.  Run `git config --list` to verify that everything is correct.

You can also try playing with interactive rebasing to edit a commit.

1. Enter interactive rebase `git rebase -i <commit ID>`
2. Change the commit you want to change to `edit`, save and exit
3. Recommit with a different author `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Question [Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit).

With only a few commits you can manually do:

1. `git rebase --root -i` to rebase everything from current HEAD to its root.
2. change the lines for all commits to `edit`
3. The rebase starts now at the first commit
4. Amend current commit: `git commit --amend --author "Name <email>"`
5. Continue the rebase: `git rebase --continue`
6. Repeat steps 4 & 5 until all commits are through

`"Name <email>"` has to be your wished name and email of course.

With more than a few commits this manual approach might get cumbersome.

PS: This messes up your repo-history, because the author information is included when generating the sha-hash for the commit. So do this with care. Next time set up your user.name and user.email properly.