# How to remove user commited with user from Pull request?

Tags: git, github

I `forked` a `repo`. Worked on it and then submitted my `pull request`. However, the repository owner wanted the `commits to be squashed`. While squashing commits, I had many `merge conflicts`. After squashing all the commits, now my PR shows `"user B committed with user A"`, where `user B` is the `other guy` and `user A` is `me`. How can I **remove** that `"user A commited with user B"`? How can I make the PR show only my commits instead of taking others and combining it? I tried various answers from stack overflow. This [Removing <user> committed with <user> on Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911335/removing-user-committed-with-user-on-github) might work for commits which are local. But I have already pushed everything.
Please help.

Comment: Are you quoting a commit message when you say `user B committed with user A` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, commit message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git filter-branch` to change the author and the commiter.

Copy the following script and replace the following:

- 012345: Commit number
- Name Here: Your name (2 occurrences)
- email@here.com: Your email (2 occurrences)

---

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
'if test "$GIT_COMMIT" = "012345"; then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Name Here"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Name Here"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="email@here.com"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="email@here.com"
fi' && rm -fr "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/refs/original/"
```

---

Be careful: it will rewrite the history and you may have to use `git push --force` if you already pushed.

Comment: I deleted my answer and upvoted this because I don't believe `git commit --amend` has the ability to change the committer.  I think we need `fitler-branch` for that.