# Is there any simple way changing git committer?

Tags: git, commit

I found a very weird issue today. We have two teams working on the same repo, but different branch.

Let's say, team-A working on branch *AA*; and team-B working on branch *BB*.

The spooky things just happened without any sign, i found lots of commits were brought from *BB* to *AA* by a team-A member along with his one specific commit as below.

[image]

This is the commit from team-A member, but the **Parent** field points to a commit which belongs to *BB*(which is impossibble in my opinion). That might be the reason this commit brought lots of commits from another branch.

I just talked to team-A member, he never checkout *BB*(i saw his repo, there is no local branch *BB*), Does anyone know how could it happen? and why?

Is it possible a bug of `Git` or `WebStorm`? Team-A member is using git `1.9.1` and WebStorm `Build #WS-162.1121.31, built on July 9, 2016`.

Edited:

So far, while executing `git reflog`, i found one questionably command executed `13579cd8d HEAD@{202}: reset: moving to 13579cd8`. I am pretty sure this team-A member won't do that(he never know there is a branch *BB*, not to know the commit `13579cd8` on it). And he's using WebStorm as working tool, so might be bug of WS, or he has some misoperation

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit).

Comment: The `team-A` member didn't even know there is a branch *BB*. And i am sure he would never do `rebase -i`.  Is there any other may? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- One reason can be commits of `BB` are merged with `remote/master` and then any member of `team-A` pull `remote/master` into `AA`.
- Or, If `team-A` member pull branch `BB` directly into `AA` (`git pull origin BB`) then, `BB's` commits will be available in `AA`.

Comment: The team-A member is quite junior, he does even know there is a branch *BB*, so i don't think he would typing `git pull origin BB`. But for the first reason you mentioned, is there any way that command can be done by IDE(he is using WebStorm). Thanks

Comment: * First, make sure the `BB's` commits are available in `master`. `git checkout master && git pull origin master`. Then check if the commits are available here. *  "that command can be done by IDE" - yes the command can be easily by `VCS | git | git branches | origin/master | merge` in WebStorm.

Comment: I checked just now, *BB*'s commits only available on *BB*. Thanks for your quick answer, i will dig further more

Answer (score 1):

You have snipped so much that it is not possible to tell whether the commit in question is a merge commit.  I suspect it is: that someone ran `git merge`, perhaps by running `git pull` (`git pull` runs `git fetch` and after the fetch is done, runs either `git merge` or `git rebase`, defaulting to the wrong one—I advise new users to avoid `git pull` as its convenience turns out to be more of a trap than a help).

#### Background

The default (single) parent of a new commit is the current commit.  Branch *names* are not relevant to this part of the process; what matters is the current *commit*.

When you make a new ordinary commit with `git commit`, this is what normally happens, in this order:

1. Git checks that the *index* (also called the *staging area*) has different content from the `HEAD` commit.  (This is to prevent you from accidentally making trivial commits with no difference from the previous commit.)
2. Git collects a commit message.
3. Git turns the index into a snapshot.
4. Git writes a new commit with:

   - the message you provided as the log message,
   - the user making the commit as both author and committer,
   - the current time and date as the time-stamp, and
   - the current commit ID (from `git rev-parse HEAD`) as the parent commit ID.
5. Finally, Git takes the new commit ID generated in step 4 and writes that to the current branch name.

Note that except for step 5—the part that updates the current branch, so that the new commit as now at the branch's tip—the current branch's *name* does not enter into the picture here.  (Of course the last step *is* important, in the end.)

There are various ways to modify the above steps, e.g., `git commit --amend` sets the new commit's parent(s) the same as the current commit's parent(s), and doing a regular merge that is either conflicted, or stopped-before-committing (via `--no-commit`), leaves behind traces that make the next commit record multiple parents.  And of course a regular (successful) merge writes a commit with at least two parents, i.e., a merge commit.

Besides the above, two of the bullet-point items—author and committer, and the corresponding time-stamps—can be set to anything the person making the commit likes, either through configuration items (`user.name` and `user.email`) or through environment variables (`GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`, and so on).  The `git commit` command even has flags `--author=` and `--date=` to override them.

So, there are multiple ways for these things to happen, and branch names are the wrong place to focus.  What matters is not so much the names, as the commit IDs.  Of course, the new commit—whether it is an ordinary commit from `git commit`, or a merge commit from `git merge`—does go on the *current branch*, so here the name does matter.

#### Merge commits

I mentioned *merge commits* several times above.  A merge commit is simply a commit with two or more parents.  More than two is unusual—it's called an *octopus merge*, and mostly they are made by mistake when people run `git pull`, because `git pull` doesn't do what people expect it to do.

The *first* parent of any merge commit is handled the same way as the *only* parent of any ordinary, non-merge commit: it's the commit that was current when you made the merge.  The *second* parent, and any additional parents, are all the other commits you passed as arguments to `git merge`.

Note that if you mistakenly do:

```
git pull origin branch1 branch2
```

Git translates this into, in effect:<sup>1</sup>

```
git fetch origin &&
  git merge origin/branch1 origin/branch2   # DANGER
```

This second command, merging two branches into the current branch, is what makes an octopus merge.  Chances are you did not want that.

(Recovering from this is ... annoying and difficult, once it's pushed back.  Until then, it's not too bad: as long as you keep the mistake in your own Git repository, you can back it out without consequences to anyone else, using `git reset`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some minor technical differences in the `git merge` step, since it's actually done by commit IDs recorded in `FETCH_HEAD` and with an explicit merge commit message that uses, e.g., "branch 'branch1' of remote 'origin'" as its string, rather than "remote-tracking branch 'origin/branch1'" as its string.  But the *idea* is the same.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. The thing is, i really have no idea what happened to team-A member's laptop. I can only describe what i saw.
So far, while executing `git reflog`, i found one questionably command executed `13579cd8d HEAD@{202}: reset: moving to 13579cd8dc6cc5e48ba604371d0376704f8644cc`.  I am pretty sure this member won't do that(junior developer). And he using WebStorm as working tool, so might be bug of WS, or he has some misoperation. 

Thanks for your detailed explaination

Comment: I know nothing of WebStorm, so it could be a bug there, I wouldn't know. :-)