# Change Git Author Information in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, git-filter-branch

I have a team project in Visual Studio Team Services and I'm using git as a version control system.

Is it possible to change the author name and email of the commits in Visual Studio website ?

Comment: Talking about pure git, the answer is "yes". If it's many revisions, you might consider using git filter-branch to do it. If it's only a few revisions, you might consider amending them (and cherry-pick whatever was on top of them). https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: I know how to do that for local git projects. But I want to do it in visualstudio.com because my project is hosted there. I couldn't find any option in the website for changing the author information.

Comment: Can't do the change locally and then use ```git push -f``` to force whatever you have locally to replace the remote content?

Comment: @Edmundo It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

Your author name and email address is bound to your commits and mostly taken from your global Git settings, not your VSTS account. Change your display info through `Team Explorer > Settings > Repository Settings`.

[image: Git name and email]

---

In case you want to change it through Git shell:

> To set your username for a specific repository, enter the following command in the root folder of your repository:

```
git config user.name "Billy Everyteen"
# Set a new name
git config user.name
# Verify the setting
Billy Everyteen
```

[Source](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)

---

**EDIT:** Just noticed you're talking about existing commits, take a look at [Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit).

Comment: Addition: If you want to set `user.name` for a repo you probably want to set `user.email` as well.