# how to rename author name in GIT version control after pushed many changes?

Tags: git, version-control

I am using `git` version control.
I've committed and pushed some changes with my first name as author name. then many authors committed and pushed our changes, but now I need to change the committed author name only not message.
Is any way to do this changes?

Comment: Have you pushed yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit)

Comment: You have to rewrite the commit in question.  If you've already pushed, then get ready for a mess, especially if others have pulled your commit already.  If you _haven't_ pushed yet, then check the duplicate link for how to rewrite that commit with a different author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to change the author name for all the commit histories. You can use `git filter-branch` to change the author name:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "old name" ];
        then
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="new name";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD
```

It will take a few minutes to rewrite the commit history.

After that you can use `git push -f --all` to update the remote repo.

Comment: WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
         rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
         alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
         (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
         filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
         set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't pushed yet:

1. Undo the commit with `git reset --soft HEAD^`
2. Change your name with `git config --global user.name "Berry M."`
3. Commit your changes again.

Comment: i was committed and pushed around 100 changes

Comment: If you mean to tell me you've already pushed, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit as @tim-biegeleisen mentioned in the comments above.