# GitHub not showing my profile

Tags: github, git-commit, git-push

Github show my user name but it is disable. but when I commit  other project there show my name. I don't know what is the issue here

[image]

and project not showing my account is contributor

contributor should be showing 3 but it still showing 2 not showing me

what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your commit author name and email, which derives from your lcoal configuration `user.name` and `user.email`.

For GitHub to show your GitHub user, you need the exact name *and* email of your GitHub account when creating commits.

In your local repo, type:

```
 git log --pretty=format:"%H %an %ae %ad" --date=short
```

`an` and `ae` stands for author name and author email.

If you are alone working on the repo, you can [amend author/email for your local commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30737248/6309), and then `git push --force`.

Comment: how can I do this ? would you help me please

Comment: @NazmulHasan I have edited the answer.

Comment: I seem contributor user name and email  not me . but I commit since `2017-07-16`  what should I do?

Comment: @NazmulHasan I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just try to access your git repo using github desktop application. And may be you are not authenticated to use that repo that's why your name is coming like that.

Comment: it is not an answer . it should be comment