# Changing git history of Github repo

Tags: git, github

What is the easiest way to change the git history of my repository (e.g., "repo.git") in a way that does not wipe all my files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GitHub you can find an article about this: [Changing author info](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/#platform-linux).

Otherwise, I think you will need to rebase your repo and then push again (however you should never do that on shared repository).

Check this link: [Git Tools - Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

and this answer [change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit)

Hope it helps..