# How to combine number of commits of same author

Tags: git, github

I have been contributing to an open source project. At first, all my commits were under name `yathartha`. But after a while, I changed the name to `Yathartha Joshi` and now my new commits are under this name. So is it possible to combine the number of commits? If so how, otherwise what can I do to combine them.

I have 8 commits under `yathartha` and 14 commits under `Yathartha Joshi`.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit

Comment: You need to rewrite those commits and thus rewrite the history. If you're contributing to someone elses project I'm almost certain you will just have to live with this.

Comment: GitHub Help https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-when-i-change-my-username/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project has a `.mailmap` under the root, you can add this line to it:

```
Yathartha Joshi <oldmail@xxx> yathartha <newmail@xxx>
```

The second name and email will be replaced by the first. If the mail is not changed, the `newmail` part can be omitted.

Not sure if it works for the number on Github. `.mailmap` is used to help `git shortlog` summarize the output of `git log`. Before this line is added, `git shortlog --all` displays:

```
yathartha (8):
      commit1
      commit2
      ...
      commit8

Yathartha Joshi (14):
      commit9
      ...
      commit22
```

And afterwards, it displays:

```
Yathartha Joshi (22):
      commit1
      commit2
      ...
      commit22
```