# How to change the username for a GitHub commit?

Tags: git, github, user-controls

I used my brother's laptop to upload a project onto my Github. The username it used was my brother's. So, although the files are posted to the correct repo. The credit for uploading the branch is given to my brother's account. How do I change the credit for uploading the branch to my account? Also, how do I login to my Github account on terminal?

Comment: I think this is repeated: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your username and email using the following git commands

```
 git config --global user.name "John Doe"
 git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```