# How do I update the author for Git commits in a merged branch?

Tags: git

I have been following [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit#3042512) guides on how to update the authors for commits in Git, but I haven't managed to update the Author for a branch that was previously merged.

Here is what the commit history looks like:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G
         \ 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6...
```

So far I've managed to re-write the authors of the top branch. Although it's not easy to find: In something like Gitlab if you view commit C and then follow the links to the parent commit a few times you will eventually find commits where the Author hasn't updated in commits 3, 4, 5 etc.

How can I update these?

The script I ran to update most of the commits was:

```
git filter-branch -f --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "OLD-USER" ];
        then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="NEW-USER";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="NEW-USER";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="NEW-EMAIL";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="NEW-EMAIL";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD
```

### Edit

Thanks to [Greg Hewgill's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730163/6530181) answer, the below script fixed it

```
git filter-branch -f --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "OLD-USER" ];
        then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="NEW-USER";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="NEW-USER";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="NEW-EMAIL";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="NEW-EMAIL";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' -- --all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `HEAD` at the end of your command line, you have only changed the history for the current branch. To change the history for all branches, replace `HEAD` with `-- --all`.

From the [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) documentation:

> **<rev-list options>…​**
>
> Arguments for *git rev-list*. All positive refs included by these options are rewritten. You may also specify options such as `--all`, but you must use `--` to separate them from the *git filter-branch* options.