# Same user set after changing username globally to git

Tags: git

I am trying to Push on Git. I successfully changed my username & email by using

```
git config --global user.email "demo@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "demo"
```

But When Pushing to Git, It is giving me error remote: Permission to username denied to perviously set username. Unable to access.

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: Pretty sure your commit credentials have nothing to do with this error

Comment: Can you show the actual output of git rather than paraphrasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat speculative, but the issue could have to do with that some of the commits in your local branch still bear the incorrect username and/or email address.  Type `git log` on the branch to check, and in particular pay attention to the new commits you have locally which the remote does not already know about.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/how-to-change-the-commit-author-for-one-specific-commit) for a number of methods to change the commit author for a Git branch.

Comment: I could be wrong, but if so, then we can rule out your history as being the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just follow these commands,

- sudo dnf install git
- git config --global user.name " "
- git config --global user.email
- git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=31536000'