# How can I undo the unexpected push to GitHub with another user credentials

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-revert

I'm simultaneously working with my github repositories and client git repository. Today, I did modifications on my git code and unexpectedly committed with client credentials. After commit I realised that I committed the code with client username and email, then I set `git config --global user.name "myname"` and `git config --global user.email "ex@gmail.com"` to push the code to my repo. Code pushed successfully. But my problem is, I can see the commit was made by client credentials. And also his name added to contributors list. You can see below 
[image: You can see here:] How can I remove him from my contributors and I want to undo the push completely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3042437/1030675

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is the last commit, you can edit the message and reset the author with `git commit --amend --reset-author` to set it to your current config.

Then, you have to `git push --force` the push to remove the commit with the wrong author.

If this is not the last commit, you can use `git rebase --interactive` and reset the commit you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did `git revert e4dc6fd `. What should I do now?

Comment: If this is the last commits, you can do `git reset HEAD^` to cancel the last commit. Or you can do `git rebase --interactive e4dc6fd^` (I assume `e4dc6fd` is the commit you want to change the author), then mark the commit `e4dc6fd` to edit it, then close the editor to run the rebase, and when it stops, do `git commit --amend --reset-author`

Comment: To check what your previous git history looks like, you can do `git log --all --decorate --graph --pretty=oneline --topo-order`

Comment: Thank you @Asenar