# Git uses unexpected user when I commit from PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

I recently share my laravel project on github using PhpStorm. I afraid why PhpStorm is using `hackerrank` as git user on my project?

`hackerrank Removed h3 commented code.`

This is the recently commit I have pasted above. All commits are with the `hackerrank` user.

Repository is private so I can't share.

Comment: Do you see this used when you do `git config --get-all user.name` ?

Comment: Yes I saw this, but don't know why it is set automatically. I have only 2 commits.

Comment: `user.name=hackerrank
user.email=me@hackerrank.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would roll like this:

1. Change user name and e-mail.

   Supposedly you want to do this locally in your Laravel project.

   `cd` to that project's directory and run

   ```
   $ git config --local user.name Asif
   $ git config --local user.email asif@example.com
   ```
2. Re-write your commits in order to update their metadata:

   ```
   $ git filter-branch --env-filter '
       GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=Asif
       GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=asif@example.com
       GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
       GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
       export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
       export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
      ' -- --all
   ```

   (See `git help filter-branch` for more info.)
3. Force-push the updated history to Github.

Note that merely running `git commit --amend` as suggested elsewhere is not going to work for two reasons:

- It does not change the author's parameters — unless the `--reset-author` command-line option was supplied.
- It does nothing to commits down the history chain.

Comment: I'm not asking the solution, I want to know why it is happen? why that name is assigned?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your user with:

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email me@me.com
```

And then amend your commit with `reset-author` (thanks to kostix' comment)

```
git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author
```

This will set your user correctly for the last commit.

For a specific commit/author, you should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042512/6320039).

Comment: I believe the question is not how to change the name, but what could have set it to "hackerrank"

Comment: Oh thanks. I'll let my answer for the time op can see it, and delete it afterward if he doesn't say anything.

Comment: @lucidbrot, if so, I'd be tempted to remove the `git` tag as Git won't change anything related to _this_ bit of configuration under no known circumstances. Otherwise, the question may also ask how to "undo" this feat of whatever piece of software did it (I suppose it's PhpStorm).

Comment: Please note that w/o the `--reset-author` command-line option, the author of the rebased commit won't be changed.

Comment: @kostix I am obviously not sure how it was meant. But the git tag might be justified if e.g. the user setting can be changed by adding a config file to the index

Comment: @lucidbrot, see, if we were to nitpick, the question does not even contain any question. I reckon, English is supposedly not the author's native language, so we sorta should guess a little bit. That what I did.

Comment: Sorry both of you about my English. I want to know that who did this? and how to stop in the future projects?

Comment: Clearly, the name `hakerrank` is unlikely to be assigned automatically by any kind of software I can think of. I'd hence start working from there. Supposedly you did something related to that site's tasks, right?

Comment: Oh I got it. I took a test on hakerrank a long ago in which one step was about to commits using their details. Thanks.