# Git push error: expected committer email 'xxxx' but found 'yyyy'

Tags: git, push

When doing a `git push` I get the following error:

```
remote: Push rejected.
remote:
remote: refs/heads/features/PLA-1458: 70f23668f033dd59daa116a23c6e63dc0342890f: expected committer email 'j.c@xxxx.com' but found 'j.c@yyyy.com'
remote:
remote: refs/heads/features/PLA-1458: 996b28e37a6ae63d79decd8a773a555913d0fa4e: expected committer email 'j.c@xxxx.com' but found 'j.c@yyyy.com'
remote:
remote:
To https://www.company.net/stash/scm/abc/123.git
 ! [remote rejected] features/PLA-1458 -> features/PLA-1458 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://www.company.net/stash/scm/abc/123.git'
```

my global config has the correct email address:

```
user.email=j.c@xxxx.com
```

when I do a git log and check the commits that are mentioned in the error:

```
70f23668f033dd59daa116a23c6e63dc0342890f
```

and

```
996b28e37a6ae63d79decd8a773a555913d0fa4e
```

I can see the correct email address:

```
commit 70f23668f033dd59daa116a23c6e63dc0342890f 
Author: J C <j.c@xxxx.com> 
Date:   Tue Jun 18 10:08:50 2019 +0200

commit 996b28e37a6ae63d79decd8a773a555913d0fa4e 
Author: J C <j.c@xxxx.com> 
Date:   Fri Jun 14 16:18:44 2019 +0200
```

Checking on the server side the email address is

```
j.c@xxxx.com
```

it looks like at some point a commit was made with the wrong email address `j.c@yyyy.com` and it needs to be amended now, but I dont know where it is or how to do it. Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/how-to-change-the-commit-author-for-one-specific-commit/28845565 may be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: The error message says committer email, not author email. Did you try using `git log --pretty=fuller` to print both author and committer information?

Alternatively, you could use `git cat-file -p <commit_hash>` to print the raw contents of the commit object.

Comment: aha! you are right I can see the committer email now on those commits being the wrong one. now, how do I change them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Alderath the problem was the Commiter email, not the author.

i used this code:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

to correct the email on all commits on all branches as shown in this answer: [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi?rq=1)