# git config --global or git push isn't working. Bitbucket related

Tags: git, bitbucket, babun

So I have been trying to git push to a remote repository. It usually works but it wasn't until recently I have been getting these errors.

```
Your local git email (git config --global user.email) does not match
the one associated with your BitBucket account. This can be set via
the command: git config --global user.email <email>

Your local git username (git config --global user.name) does not match
the one associated with your BitBucket account. This can be set via
the command: git config --global user.name <"User Name>

expected committer name 'My, Name' but found 'Anonymous'
```

I used git log and put in the exact same name/email that I have been using but it won't save or acknowledge. I still get these errors. When I use the command it tells me, nothing happens. I was told to use a git rebase but I have no idea how to use that or what it is even. For some reason it still has me under Anonymous even after I use the command it tells me to change it and put my email/name to match what is on my Bitbucket account. Any suggestions?

EDIT: When I type

```
git config --global user.name
```

and

```
git config --global user.email
```

It tells me the correct name and email its suppose to say

Comment: Is the output of git config user.name also correct? (Without --global flag)

Comment: Yes. I am doing the rebase right now of all past times I pushed and changing the author

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would have to change the email address on your previous commits. You can change the email address on all of your previous commits with:

`git rebase --root --exec "git commit --amend --author='name <email>' --no-edit"`

You can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/how-to-change-the-commit-author-for-one-specific-commit) and its answers for more options about changing the email address on one or more specific commits (if you don't want to change all of them).

Comment: Do I type it in exactly like this, all one line, but only put my name and email in the `--author='name <email>'` section? With the single & double quotes and `<>` included aswell?

Comment: Single & double quotes — yes; `<>` — yes, but please understand that `name <email>` has 2 placeholders: you must put your real name and email, not literal words `name` and `email`.