# How to change the git name and email in previous 3 commits

Tags: github, gitlab, commit

I want to change to name and email of my in previous 3 commits

Can you tell me how can I change that?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/how-to-change-the-commit-author-for-one-specific-commit. Answer includes how-to for any number of commits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the commit author for one specific commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/how-to-change-the-commit-author-for-one-specific-commit)