# GitHub Desktop commits showing as another user, despite being on the same account

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Here is the issue - In the image below, I committed the python files for the first time
[image: commits showing as a different user]

so, how do I fix this?
[image: image showing me logged in on my account]

as you can clearly see, I'm logged in as the same account, but in commit history it shows as two different users.
[image]

Comment: I think for some reason your author information was not configured when you committed the specific change. This link - [How to change the commit author for one specific commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042512/4909849) might help answer your question.

Comment: This will definetly help, thank you!