# To Add email to commits already made

Tags: git, github

I just realized that the commits I have been making in a new github account are not being counted as contributions in Githubs contribution calendar, since I was committing with a Generic email address (`jane@computer.local`style).

Is there any way to change the email addres, so those (already made) commits are credited and counted to that account?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [How to change the commit author for one specific commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3042437/11082165)

Comment: If the commits are already pushed to the upstream repo and it's shared with several persons, like a public repository, there is really no way to controlledly update the repo in place. The only safe fix is to create a new repository entirely, with its history rewritten to replace the committer information. If this is in a temporary branch or a private repository, perhaps you can agree to have everyone accept a force push and update their copies at a time you arrange between you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+email+multiple+commits