# Commit as repo owner when logged in different account on git desktop?

Tags: git

When im logged in `Github Desktop` with account `XXX`, and commit a file to a repo from a different account `YYY` using a token like:

```
git pull
git add .
git push https://YYY:ghp_...@github.com/YYY/... main
```

The file is uploaded to `YYY` repo and on Github website it displays the files has been committed by the `XXX` account.

How do i upload it as if it where being uploaded from `YYY` account and not `XXX`?

Do i need to logout from `Github Desktop` first?

Comment: "committed by `XXX`" is based on the *commit author*. You have to rewrite your commits locally to set their author to `YYY` before pushing. The credentials used to push do not affect the authorship.

Comment: See question suggested as duplicate, or : https://stackoverflow.com/q/3042437/86072