# Git is showing the system name in the commit instead of username

Tags: git, github

I have updated the git creds using these commands

```
git config --global user.email myemail@gmail.com

git config --global user.name myusername
```

But when I pushed the code it is also showing the **system name** in the **commit** as well. How can I change it to **my name**?

Edit: Output of the `git log -n 1`

```
Author: MySystemName <XXXX>   // this is exact what I get in git commit
Date:   Sun Apr 2 20:54:31 2023 +0530
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific non-global setting in the project itself? This would override the global setting.

Comment: @tripleee  I guess no but How can I check that or set that?

Comment: I am guessing: `git config --global --list`, but not knowing the exact line, and response, from your "git push", I will remain guessing....

Comment: Concretely, does `git config user.name` output something different than `git config --global user.name`?

Comment: Please update your question  to show the output of `git log -n 1`.We don't know *how* it's showing the system name.

Comment: @tripleee both command showing the same `username`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Updated the question please check this what I wanted to change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the commit author for a single commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/how-to-change-the-commit-author-for-a-single-commit)

Comment: @tripleee Yes This does the trick. Can I set it so that I do not mention every time `--author <>`?

Comment: Once you have configured Git properly it will remember.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee I am able to change the author can I change the `committer` also?

Comment: These are very common FAQs; please search instead of asking somebody else to find the information for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I check that or set that?

Go to your repository folder, and type:

```
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope
```

You will see *all* settings, with their scope and location. If there is one closer to the repository with your system name, it would take precedence over the global settings.

Check also for [user environment variables, like "Committing"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_committing):

> - `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` is the human-readable name in the “author” field.
> - `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` is the email for the “author” field.
> - `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` sets the human name for the “committer” field.
> - `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` is the email address for the “committer” field.

Those would also take precedence over the global settings.

---

For existing commits, you can use [`git filter-repo`](https://ansible.caceis.group.gca/#/jobs/237897) (to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)) "[User and email based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_user_and_email_based_filtering)":

```
cd repo
git filter-repo --mailmap my-mailmap
```

with `my-mailmap`:

```
Correct Name <correct@email.com> <old@email.com>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to change the Author name. Can you please check my updated question

Comment: @AshishChoudary Sure, I have edited the answer to address your edit.