# Git: How to permanently removed record of a specific author after changing commit author by git rebase

Tags: git, github

I have followed [How to change the commit author for a single commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/how-to-change-the-commit-author-for-a-single-commit) to successfully change my author history of my previous commit.

However in my github page, the contributors is still showing my two accounts although I already wiped out everything, as shown here:
[Two contributors as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75OUr.png)

How should I remove it permanently?